# How often should you use git-gc?

Tags: git, git-gc

How often should you use git-gc?

The [manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) simply says:

> Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk space utilization and good operating performance.

Are there some commands to get some object counts to find out whether it's time to gc?

Comment: Tasks like these are prime candidates for cron (if you are using linux) http://minhajuddin.com/2011/12/09/gc-your-git-repositories-automatically-with-a-cron-task/

Comment: Note: setting **`gc.autodetach`** (Git 2.0 Q2 2014) can help running `git gc --auto` without bloking the user. see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22358144/6309).

Answer (score 232, accepted):

It depends mostly on how much the repository is used.  With one user checking in once a day and a branch/merge/etc operation once a week you probably don't need to run it more than once a year.

With several dozen developers working on several dozen projects each checking in 2-3 times a day, you might want to run it nightly.

It won't hurt to run it more frequently than needed, though.

What I'd do is run it now, then a week from now take a measurement of disk utilization, run it again, and measure disk utilization again.  If it drops 5% in size, then run it once a week.  If it drops more, then run it more frequently.  If it drops less, then run it less frequently.

Comment: Manual says "Some git commands run git gc --auto after performing operations that could create many loose objects."  Anyone know which commands actually run it?

Comment: A large git rebase is an obvious example, since many commits are rewritten into a new history - leaving lots of old commits in your repo which are part of the current branch anymore

Comment: "It won't hurt to run it more frequently than needed"... I don't entirely agree. As Aristotle points out, dangling commits can make a good backup mechanism.

Answer (score 124):

Note that the downside of garbage-collecting your repository is that, well, the garbage gets collected. As we all know as computer users, files we consider garbage right now might turn out to be very valuable three days in the future. The fact that git keeps most of its debris around has saved my bacon several times – by browsing all the dangling commits, I have recovered much work that I had accidentally canned.

So don’t be too much of a neat freak in your private clones. There’s little need for it.

OTOH, the value of data recoverability is questionable for repos used mainly as remotes, eg. the place all the devs push to and/or pulled from. There, it might be sensible to kick off a GC run and a repacking frequently.

Comment: FWIW not all loose objects are garbage collected, only those older than 2 week by default (cf. `git gc --help`, specifically the `--prune` option). There is also mention of `gc.reflogExpire`, which leads me to believe that any commitish you've visited in the last 90 days will not be collected. (My git version: v1.7.6)

Answer (score 34):

Recent versions of git run gc automatically when required, so you shouldn't have to do anything. See the Options section of [man git-gc(1)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html#_options): "Some git commands run git gc --auto after performing operations that could create many loose objects."

Comment: I just ran it for the first time on a several-year-old repository, and my .git went from 16M to 2.9M, an 82% reduction in size.  It therefore still seems useful to manually run the command.

Comment: @DarshanRivkaWhittle had you updated git in those several years?

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave Yeah, I was always running whatever version was current on Arch.  I just ran it again, maybe for the first time since my last comment (thanks to your comment reminding me), and my .git went from 81M to 13M.  I must not run any of the commands that run `gc --auto`, I guess.

Answer (score 23):

If you're using [**Git-Gui**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui), it [tells you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui) when you should worry:

> ```
> This repository currently has approximately 1500 loose objects.
> ```

The following command will bring a similar number:

```
$ git count-objects
```

Except, [from its source](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=ixHQFFqenblz1kBNxchs4xCFe6w&cid=S766kQUyJJc&s=%22This%20repository%20currently%20has%20approximately%22&fp=288055&mpundefined=&projSelected=true&filterCheckedundefined=&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1#L107), git-gui will do the math by itself, actually counting something at `.git/objects` folder and probably brings an approximation (I don't know `tcl` to properly read that!).

In any case, it **seems** to give the warning based on an arbitrary number *around* 300 loose objects.

Comment: Indeed it does warn, but upon letting it run gc, most of the time gc wont do a thing. So relying on git gui to do it, is to wait for more than 6000something loose objects with always having to click on either run gc and wait for a minute or cancel :/ Probably someone should fix git gui in a way that it checks max loose object count and not bother to show the dialog until the count reaches the limit.

Comment: Yes @mlatu I agree. When I wrote this I just wanted to bring attention to it. Both `Git-Gui` and `count-objects` are not exactly good answers to the question here... But they should be!

Comment: i didnt mean that this is a bad answer, just wanted to point out that most of the time git gui does nothing. though i suppose git gc doesnt do much either, except when there is enough to do or you used the aggressive switch.

Answer (score 8):

Drop it in a cron job that runs every night (afternoon?) when you're sleeping.

Comment: Should I done it for the all github repositories?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it without any interruption, with the new (Git 2.0 Q2 2014) setting [**`gc.autodetach`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.1.0#git-config-gcautodetach).

See [commit 4c4ac4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c4ac4db2c933fbae1c6e6bcf90d9bee5f823fc7) and [commit 9f673f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f673f9477c63433aa0774c11b9e42979721f4d6) ([Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy, aka pclouds](https://github.com/pclouds)):

> `gc --auto` takes time and can block the user temporarily (but not any less annoyingly).
>   Make it run in background on systems that support it.
>   The only thing lost with running in background is printouts. But `gc output` is not really interesting.
>   You can keep it in foreground by changing `gc.autodetach`.

---

Since that 2.0 release, there was a bug though: git 2.7 (Q4 2015) will make sure to **not lose the error message**.
See [commit 329e6e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/329e6e8794c347d3da92144f88ad838945508ac6) (19 Sep 2015) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 076c827](https://github.com/git/git/commit/076c8278583b70547c1c5a65941a661f08210252), 15 Oct 2015)</sup>

> ### `gc`: save log from daemonized `gc --auto` and print it next time
>
> While [commit 9f673f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f673f9477c63433aa0774c11b9e42979721f4d6) (`gc`: config option for running `--auto` in background - 2014-02-08) helps reduce some complaints about '`gc --auto`' hogging the terminal, it creates another set of problems.
>
> The latest in this set is, as the result of daemonizing, `stderr` is closed and all warnings are lost. This warning at the end of `cmd_gc()` is particularly important because it tells the user how to avoid "`gc --auto`" running repeatedly.
>   Because stderr is closed, the user does not know, naturally they complain about '`gc --auto`' wasting CPU.
>
> **Daemonized `gc` now saves `stderr` to `$GIT_DIR/gc.log`.
>
>   Following `gc --auto` will not run and `gc.log` printed out until the user removes `gc.log`**.

Answer (score 8):

This quote is taken from;
[Version Control with Git](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316387)

> **Git runs garbage collection automatically**:
>
> • If there are too many loose objects in the repository
>
> • When a push to a remote repository happens
>
> • After some commands that might introduce many loose objects
>
> • When some commands such as  git reflog expire explicitly request it
>
> And finally, garbage collection occurs when you explicitly request it
> using the  git gc command. But when should that be? There’s no solid
> answer to this question, but there is some good advice and best
> practice.
>
> **You should consider running  git gc manually in a few
> situations:**
>
> • If you have just completed a  git filter-branch . Recall that
> filter-branch rewrites many commits, introduces new ones, and leaves
> the old ones on a  ref that should be removed when you are satisfied
> with the results. All those dead objects (that are no longer
> referenced since you just removed the one  ref pointing to them)
> should be removed via garbage collection.
>
> • After some commands that might introduce many loose objects. This
> might be a large rebase effort, for example.
>
> **And on the flip side,
> when should you be wary of garbage collection?**
>
> • If there are orphaned refs that you might want to recover
>
> • In the context of  git rerere and you do not need to save the
> resolutions forever
>
> • In the context of only tags and branches being sufficient to cause
> Git to retain a commit permanently
>
> • In the context of  FETCH_HEAD retrievals (URL-direct retrievals via
> git fetch ) because they are immediately subject to garbage collection

Comment: I have unreachable commits in my tree (as a result of `git commit --amend`). This can be verified with `git log --reflog`. I pushed a branch to the remote repository and checked my tree again; the unreachable commits were still there. Apparently `git gc` was not run when this push happened. … ?

Comment: From https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-gc:`gc.reflogExpire`: `An optional variable that defaults to 90 days. It is used to set how long records in a branches reflog should be preserved.`

Answer (score 7):

I use git gc after I do a big checkout, and have a lot of new object. it can save space. E.g. if you checkout a big SVN project using git-svn, and do a git gc, you typically save a lot of space

Comment: Is this still true?  Even in '08 HDD space was cheap, using that as a justification to run it seems pointless

Answer (score 4):

I use when I do a big commit, above all when I remove more files from the repository.. after, the commits are faster

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use `git gc` very often, because `git gc` (Garbage collection) is run automatically on several frequently used commands:

```
git pull
git merge
git rebase
git commit
```

Source: [git gc best practices and FAQS](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-gc)

Answer (score 0):

Just for a bit of another point of view, note that you can have repos where you DO NOT WANT to do garbage-collection, automatic or otherwise (used as reference repositories, possibly local clones, etc.) because some other repository uses this git index and may become invalid if objects disappear or files they are in get different names.

This may be a fairly typical situation on a space-conscious CI farm with some single repository used as a baseline (maybe even over NFS or similar) to spawn build workspaces for many different test/build scenarios. There you can `git config gc.auto false` in the repository to avoid mishaps, and use domain-specific scripting to only GC when you know it is safe to (e.g. no builds running => no agents to corrupt mid-flight) or even never.

Conversely, you may want to use a common reference repository and then detach workspace repos after instantiating the particular commit they would build (this copies just the needed objects, possibly sped up by shallowness/depth settings for that workspace) to make them independent and so reducing the time-window when it is critical to not-GC the main repository.

Some reasons to do this trickery include:

- Using a CI farm with slow link to the SCM platform (e.g. reaching out to GitHub, etc. from a corporate LAN) so that you only suffer the long-ish `git clone` or similar operations (and eat the uplink traffic which may be costly in corporate setups) once per build and not for each scenario;
- Be sure the commit you want to build is available to all agents during this build (if someone force-pushes to the original repo/branch on the SCM platform, as often happens during PR preparations from private forks, a direct checkout from it may be impossible by the time the build agent is ready to do the work because the SCM platform claims the commit hash does not exist), or for named branch builds - to ensure that the same tip commit is used in all scenarios of the same build (and yes, some teams do not shy away from redefining a `git tag` over time, too);
- As a continuation of the above - your build scenario might in fact prepare and archive a tarball of the git repository (garbage-collected and all), and distribute it to build agents as a temporary artifact for faster workspace instantiation. Such approach is more useful when the agents are not on the same build host or even same LAN.

Source/Disclaimer: lessons learned while making https://github.com/networkupstools/jenkins-dynamatrix/blob/master/src/org/nut/dynamatrix/DynamatrixStash.groovy and similar projects