# How to remove unreferenced blobs from my Git repository

Tags: git

I have a GitHub repository that had two branches - *master* and *release*.

The *release* branch contained binary distribution files that were contributing to a very large repository size (more than 250 MB), so I decided to clean things up.

First I deleted the remote release branch, via `git push origin :release`.

Then I deleted the local *release* branch. First I tried `git branch -d release`, but Git said *"error: The branch 'release' is not an ancestor of your current HEAD."* which is true, so then I did `git branch -D release` to force it to be deleted.

But my repository size, both locally and on GitHub, was still huge. So then I ran through the usual list of Git commands, like `git gc --prune=today --aggressive`, without any luck.

By following Charles Bailey's instructions at [SO 1029969](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big/1036595#1036595) I was able to get a list of SHA-1 hashes for the biggest blobs. I then used the script from [SO 460331](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460331/git-finding-a-filename-from-a-sha1/460417#460417) to find the blobs...and the five biggest don't exist, though smaller blobs are found, so I know the script is working.

I think these blogs are the binaries from the release branch, and they somehow got left around after the delete of that branch. What's the right way to get rid of them?

Comment: What version of Git are you using? And did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui/1108084#1108084 ?

Comment: git version 1.6.2.3

I'd tried gc and prune w/various arguments. I hadn't tried repack -a -d -l, just ran it, no change.

Comment: New info - a fresh clone from GitHub no longer has the unreferenced blobs, and is down to "only" 84MB from 250MB.

Answer (score 281):

I present to you this useful command, "git-gc-all", guaranteed to remove **all** your Git garbage until they might come up extra configuration variables:

```
git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 \
    -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc
```

You might also need to run something like these first:

```
git remote rm origin
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ .git/refs/remotes/ .git/*_HEAD .git/logs/
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ |
    xargs -n1 --no-run-if-empty git update-ref -d
```

You might also need to remove some tags:

```
git tag | xargs git tag -d
```

Comment: Interesting. A good alternative to my more general answer. +1

Comment: This deserves more up votes. It finally got rid of a lot of git objects other methods would keep. Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted. Wow, I don't know what I just did but it seems to clean up a lot. Can you elaborate on what it does? I have the feeling it cleared out all my `objects`. What are those and why are they (apparently) irrelevant?

Comment: @Redsandro, as I understand, those "git rm origin", "rm" and "git update-ref -d" commands remove references to old commits for remotes and such, which might be preventing garbage collection.  The options to "git gc" tell it not to hold on to various old commits, else it will hold on to them for a while.  E.g. gc.rerereresolved is for "records of conflicted merge you resolved earlier", by default kept for 60 days. Those options are in the git-gc manpage.  I'm not an expert on git and don't know exactly what all these things do.  I found them from manpages, and grepping .git for commit refs.

Comment: A git object is a compressed file or tree or commit in your git repo, including old stuff from the history.  git gc clears out unneeded objects.  It keeps objects which are still needed for your current repo, and its history.

Comment: How bad is it to run without --no-run-if-empty? (this args is not supported on osx)

Comment: @CharlesL, it doesn't matter, it will just give a harmless error message if there are no refs to delete.

Comment: I wrote a script which uses this one, to delete all history from a git repo: http://sam.nipl.net/b/git-kill-history  If run on two consistent repos it produces the same commits / hashes, so there's no need to "re-clone" after destroying history, just run `git-kill-history` on both sides.

Comment: Nothing else I tried worked, but when I ran this it immediately worked. Thanks!

Comment: What is the 'in' branch referenced in the linked script ?

Comment: Should all also mention that any tag that exists in the repository can keep history alive - since this script does not deal with them you need to remove them manually first if you want to clean history leading up tags. For example to remove all local tags you can run: `git tag | xargs git tag -d`.

Comment: @Zitrax, that 'in' branch is a temporary branch that I use so I can safely merge stuff that is pushed to that branch. Personal setup.

Comment: Don't use `git gc --aggressive`. https://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/

Comment: So this method didn't work for me. I found that references still existed inside `.git/info/refs` and `.git/packed-refs`. Removing these references with vim and then running the command succeeded. Although I'm not entirely sure the evil commits weren't still inside a pack. So I unpacked the packs as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972031/how-to-unpack-all-objects-of-a-git-repository for good measure. I would probably advise people to just do a clone and then blow away the original repository.

Comment: The method I was using to ensure that objects were deleted was `git rev-list --objects --all | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -n 1 git cat-file -p | less`.

Comment: You, Sir, are the freaking bomb! I humbly bow in reverence to your enlightening persona!

Comment: this command does nothing `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n1 --no-run-if-empty git update-ref -d`

Comment: @SamWatkins This reduces the git size of the local repo. How do we reflect this change on the remote repo also? Because it will all come back after recloning the repo. Also, `git status` doesn't show any changes so there is no way to push this `cleaning` to repo

Comment: @PankajSinghal, you could run the cleanup on the remote repo also, or remove the remore repo and create it again from the local repo.

Comment: How can we be sure, this process is sucess or not Can you add anything for this? @SamWatkins

Answer (score 128):

You can (as [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528593/2199657)) **permanently remove everything that is referenced only in the reflog**.

**WARNING**: This will remove many objects you might want to keep:

- All of your stashes.
- Old history not in any current branches.

**Read the documentation** to be sure this is what you want.

To expire the `reflog`, and then prune all objects not in branches:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

`git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all` removes all references of unreachable commits in `reflog`.

`git gc --prune=now` removes the commits themselves.

**Attention**: Only using `git gc --prune=now` will not work since those commits are still referenced in the reflog. Therefore, clearing the reflog is mandatory. Also note that if you use `rerere` it has additional references not cleared by these commands. See `git help rerere` for more details. In addition, any commits referenced by local or remote branches or tags will not be removed because those are considered as valuable data by git.

Comment: It worked, but somehow I lost my saved stashes in the process (nothing major in my case, just a caution for others)

Comment: why not --aggressive ?

Comment: I think this answer needs a clear warning, preferably at the top. My edit suggestion was rejected, because I guess I should suggest it to the author in a comment? Please either accept this edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26023988 or add a warning your own way. Also, this **drops all your stashes**. That should be memtioned in the warning too!

Comment: I tested with git version 2.17 and stashed commits will not be removed by the above commands. Are you sure you didn't run any additional commands?

Comment: `git fetch --prune` further reduce size because deleting local blobs.

Comment: How to push these repo cleanup changes in all branches?

Comment: Can this command be changed to include stashes? I would consider stashes to be part of my repository, so including them would be useful.

Comment: This did remove the unreferenced commits, but it didn't free up space on my disk

Comment: for deleting rerere records, can we use `git rerere clear &&  rm -rf .git/rr-cache` @leoly?

Answer (score 35):

As mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui/1108084#1108084), `git gc` can actually increase the size of the repo!

See also [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-08/msg00943.html)

> Now git has a safety mechanism to *not* delete unreferenced objects right away when running '`git gc`'.
>   By default unreferenced objects are kept around for a period of 2 weeks. This is to make it easy for you to recover accidentally deleted branches or commits, or to avoid a race where a just-created object in the process of being but not yet referenced could be deleted by a '`git gc`' process running in parallel.
>
> So to give that grace period to packed but unreferenced objects, the repack process pushes those unreferenced objects out of the pack into their loose form so they can be aged and eventually pruned.
>   Objects becoming unreferenced are usually not that many though. Having 404855 unreferenced objects is quite a lot, and being sent those objects in the first place via a clone is stupid and a complete waste of network bandwidth.
>
> Anyway... To solve your problem, you simply need to run '`git gc`' with the `--prune=now` argument to disable that grace period and get rid of those unreferenced objects right away (safe only if no other git activities are taking place at the same time which should be easy to ensure on a workstation).
>
> And BTW, using '`git gc --aggressive`' with a later git version (or '`git repack -a -f -d --window=250 --depth=250`')

The [same thread mentions](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-08/msg01037.html):

```
 git config pack.deltaCacheSize 1
```

> That limits the delta cache size to one byte (effectively disabling it) instead of the default of 0 which means unlimited. With that I'm able to repack that repository using the above `git repack` command on an x86-64 system with 4GB of RAM and using 4 threads (this is a quad core). Resident memory usage grows to nearly 3.3GB though.
>
> If your machine is SMP and you don't have sufficient RAM then you can reduce the number of threads to only one:

```
git config pack.threads 1
```

> Additionally, you can further limit memory usage with the `--window-memory argument` to '`git repack`'.
>   For example, using `--window-memory=128M` should keep a reasonable upper bound on the delta
>   search memory usage although this can result in less optimal delta match if the repo
>   contains lots of large files.

---

On the filter-branch front, you can consider (with cautious) [this script](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit

# Author: David Underhill
# Script to permanently delete files/folders from your git repository.  To use 
# it, cd to your repository's root and then run the script with a list of paths
# you want to delete, e.g., git-delete-history path1 path2

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# make sure we're at the root of git repo
if [ ! -d .git ]; then
    echo "Error: must run this script from the root of a git repository"
    exit 1
fi

# remove all paths passed as arguments from the history of the repo
files=$@
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $files" HEAD

# remove the temporary history git-filter-branch otherwise leaves behind for a long time
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --all &&  git gc --aggressive --prune
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository is also a good start for the `filter-branch` command usage.

Comment: Hi VonC - NI'd tried git gc prune=now with no luck. It really looks like a git bug, in that I wound up with unreferenced blobs locally following a branch deletion, but these aren't there with a fresh clone of the GitHub repo...so it's just a local repo problem.

But I have additional files that I want to clear out, so the script you referenced above is great - thanks!

Answer (score 22):

`git gc --prune=now`, or low level `git prune --expire now`.

Answer (score 14):

Each time your *HEAD* moves, Git tracks this in the `reflog`. If you removed commits, you still have "dangling commits" because they are still referenced by the `reflog` for about 30 days. This is the safety net when you delete commits by accident.

You can use the `git reflog` command to remove specific commits, repack, etc., or just the high level command:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Answer (score 3):

Before doing `git filter-branch` and `git gc`, you should review tags that are present in your repository. Any real system which has automatic tagging for things like [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and [deployments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery#Relationship_to_continuous_deployment) will make unwanted objects still referenced by these tags, hence `gc` can't remove them and you will still keep wondering why the size of the repository is still so big.

The best way to get rid of all unwanted stuff is to run `git-filter` & `git gc` and then push master to a new bare repository. The new bare repository will have the cleaned-up tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git forget-blob`.

The usage is pretty simple:

```
git forget-blob file-to-forget
```

You can get more information in *[Completely remove a file from a Git repository with 'git forget-blob'](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/18/completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-with-git-forget-blob/)*.

It will disappear from all the commits in your history, reflog, tags, and so on.

I run into the same problem every now and then, and every time I have to come back to this post and others. That's why I automated the process.

Credits go to [contributors such as Sam Watkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repository/14728706#14728706).

Comment: This damaged my git repository after I ran it. Now I get: 
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository, when I run git push origin branchname

Full error:
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

git version 2.22.0

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) - it does not remove big blobs, but it can remove big files which you specify from the whole repository. For me it reduces repository size from hundreds MB to 12 MB.

Comment: Now _that_ is a scary command :) I'll have to give it a try when my git-fu feels stronger.

Comment: you can say that again. I'm always wary of any commands that manipulate a repository's history. Things tend to go very wrong when multiple people are pushing and pulling from that repository and suddenly a bunch of objects git is expecting aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the reason that "gc" doesn't do much good is that there is an unfinished rebase or stash based on an old commit.

Comment: Or the old commit is referenced by HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, reflog or some other thing that git automatically keeps up trying to make sure it never loses anything valuable. If you really want to lose all those, you have to go the extra mile to do so.

Answer (score 1):

To add another tip, don't forget to use **git remote prune** to delete the obsolete branches of your remotes before using **git gc**.

You can see them with **git branch -a**

It's often useful when you fetch from GitHub and forked repositories...

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/verkruemelt/9245775):

> ```
> git gc --prune="0 days"
> ```