# Deploying Rails directly from GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically Deploy From GitHub To Server On Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303518/automatically-deploy-from-github-to-server-on-push)

is there a way to deploy a rails app hosted on github directly from github? without depending on services like heroku or openshift... as I have to push de git repositorie also to that servers.
Look bootstrap webpage, look, its hosted under a github domain: [Boostrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Is there a way to deploy master branch of a project like that? at least a html+css+js webpage...?

Or any service that sync automatically with github git project so I dont have to push to both servers everytime?

Comment: I think not coz, bootstrap page on github page is just a customized github page. see this for more info: http://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter Bootstrap site is a [Github Pages site](http://pages.github.com/) that uses the [gh-pages](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages) branch from the [Twitter Bootstrap repo](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap). There is no automatically deployment, it is all hosted from Github.

As to automatically deploying from Github, I would look at this answer:

[Automatically Deploy From GitHub To Server On Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303518/automatically-deploy-from-github-to-server-on-push)