# Hosting Latest Github Push (Master Branch)

Tags: git, github, hosting, push

Is there a way that I can use my github repo's latest master branch version on my website?

Basically, I want my website (fooscript.com/zombie/) (Notice the directory!) to use my github code instead of me pushing my repo, and then FTPing the files into my host, that way I can just push my tested code and boom, it's already live.

I looked into github pages and `CNAME` but I don't think that's what I want. (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-github-pages-to-host-your-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you don't have full access to your server (e.g. shared hosting). In this case, have a look at [deployhq.com](http://deployhq.com/) or [ftploy.com](http://ftploy.com).

If you do have access to your server, you can use GitHub's [post-receive hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303518/automatically-deploy-from-github-to-server-on-push). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303518/automatically-deploy-from-github-to-server-on-push) StackOverflow question for more information.

Additionally, if you are deploying to Heroku/DigitalOcean/AWS and don't want to bother setting up everything manually, you can use [dploy.io](http://dploy.io/). (First repo is free)

Comment: FTPloy is up and running and I couldn't be happier. Just a note to future readers: you need to push before any changes are made to your site! Otherwise I highly reccommend since you have 1 free project