# Laravel 5.2 Web app not showing changes after committing with github desktop

Tags: git, github, laravel-5, laravel-forge

There is this project in which I have priviledge to, and periodically I would need to update the content of the site.

It is built with laravel 5.3, hosted on linode plus laravel forge.

I made few commits to the remote, it shows the changes on GitHub but the changes does not reflect on the live web app.

Just wondering where am getting it wrong and need people who can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel server needs to add a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) listener, for listening to a [GitHub push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), and deploy the app from the latest pushed commit.

See for instance [`antonioribeiro/deeployer`](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/deeployer)

> This package is intended to be used for those that are hosting their websites in VPS (dedicated server or any other hosting provider that doesn't support web hooks).
>
> Since this package uses Laravel remote (SSH-2) functionality to remote or locally deploy applications, your deployment app can be in one server and deploy applications to others, as many as you need.

Or check out [deploybot.com](https://deploybot.com/) (there is a free plan)

Comment: the project is not using VPS, we are using Linode and Laravel Forge.

Comment: @OloyedeJamiu then you must be able to ssh to your linode server? Then https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044

Comment: @OloyedeJamiu Or you could push to it directly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37513039/6309