# Git, having permission issues pushing

Tags: linux, git

So I'm brand spanking new to Git and development in general. I'm a Linux and Mac user on a few different machines and have a couple cloud servers with AWS, I work on small little python projects on all of them.

I'll try to explain what I want first, hopefully I'm close to having the best solution that will work for my use case. I want to be able to write code on whatever device I own, Ubuntu desktop at home, work Macbook, cloud servers, Ubuntu desktop at work, and a personal Macbook. Obviously I'm working with different hostnames and usernames, I'm the only one that works on my code.

I went through the git guide and it's working, sort of. I tried to setup my repository on my cloud server which I will also be changing code on. I've been trying to commit and push from my Macbook but have been getting a string of permission errors all day, I've been having to go back to the repo and chown -R as my ssh wheel user since every object there is getting overwritten as root.

Here are some sample error messages I'm seeing when trying to push from my macbook:

A commit:

```
macbook:dev macbookuser$ git commit
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 6 commits.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

And then the push:

```
macbook:dev macbookuser$ git push
user1@myserver-aka-repo.com's password: 
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.62 KiB, done.
Total 14 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To user1@myserver-aka-repo.com:/home/myserver-aka-repo/dev/.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'user1@myserver-aka-repo.com:/home/myserver-aka-repo/dev/.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the chown and `umask 0002` don't fix this on the server, make sure the repo you are pushing to has been shared with the right mode.

```
 git config core.sharedRepository
```

See "[Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448326/6309)" for more on this option.

I usually set `core.sharedRepository` to `umask`, and set my `umask` to `0002`.