# Git: permissions modify database objects

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)

I've used Git to work with multiple co-workers on a project and it worked fine for months. A collegue of me (user A) pushed his work, made a change and pushed this change too. The first push went fine, the second push gave an error `“error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects”` All my other collegues still can push their changes.

I thought it had to do with permissions on the server, so I checked that.

```
ls -la
total 40
drwxr-sr-x 9 user      apache 4096 Dec  3 19:05 .
drwxr-sr-x 4 user      apache 4096 Sep  7 13:36 ..
drwxr-sr-x 7 root      apache 4096 Dec  3 19:31 app
drwxr-sr-x 2 root      apache 4096 Dec  3 19:05 batch
drwxr-sr-x 8 user      apache 4096 Dec 13 12:13 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      apache   24 Dec  3 19:05 .gitignore
drwxr-sr-x 5 root      apache 4096 Dec  3 19:31 lib
drwxr-sr-x 2 root      apache 4096 Nov  3 17:03 log
drwxr-sr-x 6 root      apache 4096 Dec  3 19:28 public_html
drwxr-sr-x 2 root      apache 4096 Dec  3 19:43 tmp
```

Then I compared the groups of user A with other users

```
groups otherCollegue
otherCollegue: otherCollegue apache

groups userA    
userA : userA apache
```

Both users are member of group `apache` which is owner of the git repo. SO, this doesn´t look the source of the problem to me. I think that the problems lies in the Git config or something on the side of user A, but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is that a non-bare repository on your server …? Also, more interesting would be the permissions on the `.git/objects/` directory and its children

Comment: Yes, it is a non bare server. And remember, it worked for several months. Without drastic changes it doesn't work for user A anymore

Comment: @knittl All are ownned by group `apache`