# Git Extensions: using wrong user on push

Tags: git, git-extensions

I ran into a very weird problem trying to put an existing local repository onto my server for sharing. I followed this tutorial:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server
Locally, I use Git Extensions (on Windows) with Putty, specifying the remote as `git@my_server.com`.

However, when I try to push my local repository I get:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
```

I logged into the server as user "git", went to the repository checked for problems.
All file permissions were correct (belonging to `git`) and I can create new files.
Trying to find out what went wrong I looked at the system auth log:

```
Feb 11 07:35:45 MY_SERVER sshd[22334]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_user by (uid=0)
Feb 11 07:35:47 MY_SERVER sshd[22334]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_user
```

So it looks like Git Extensions is trying to use a different user (`my_user`) to log into the system and then has some problem with permissions. This is even persistent when I generate a new private key for `git` and use this key for authentication, so it should not even be able to log is as `my_user`.

Now I often use `my_user` with Putty, but don't see how it could end up being used by Git Extensions.
Furthemore, `git` and `my_user` are in the same group and the repository is shared among the group members (`git config core.sharedRepository`), so this should not even be a problem.
I also don't understand how git can log in as `my_user`. I have used `my_users` private key in the beginning, but then replaced it. So Git Extensions must have the old settings stored somewhere.
I tried to unset the credential helper (Win Store" but that didn't change anything.

If you have any idea what is going wrong, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)

Comment: Thanks! But as I wrote: I have set BOTH the file permissions correctly (and tested it) AND set `git config core.sharedRepository`. So this issue is different.