# remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objects - why is this happening?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

While trying to push into git (using source tree) I got the following output:

```
Pushing to ssh://USERNAME@DEVGROUP.local/git/PROJECTNAME
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

(I used `USERNAME` & `PROJECTNAME` & `DEVGROUP` instead of the real output cause... copyrights...).

After a while, I tried pushing again and this time got the same output as well as this:

```
! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (unpacker error)
```

I found more then one answer to a similar problem, such as 
 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab), but everything I was able to find stated that I need to use chmod & chgrp commands, which I really don't want to use without good reason. So my question is - why is this problem appearing even if I was able to "git push" before, and how can it be fixed safely, without fear of messing with the settings?

Comment: Has anything changed either locally or remotely about which you are aware?  Any coworkers also having this problem?

Comment: No one else at my office has this problem, although a coworker said that he had a similar problem until he updated source tree, although I don't think it's related

Comment: have you tried `git fsck` ?

Comment: @Michael yes, I did. didn't really help.