# Unable to push because of insufficient permission

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Need help to resolve this as I've been working on this since Friday.

So when I'm trying to push my changes, I get this error.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to ssh://<username>/projects/ssm/ssmportal
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects        
remote: fatal: failed to write object        
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://mantis-oil.microlink.com.my/projects/ssm/ssmportal
 = [up to date]      Deployment -> Deployment
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<username>/projects/ssm/ssmportal'
```

I tried most of  what is mentioned in Google but it still does not work. What I do is to remove everything and download everything which is very tiring for me.

Can you please help me with this?

**UPDATE**

I tried the one which Chip suggested, but it still did not work. Below is the result.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114760/7004388):

First do `git pull --rebase` and

then try  `git push`

Hope you can find more information in the link provided.

Comment: tried this one, but still got the same issue. Will post all of my findings on top

Comment: Try this command `sudo chmod -R ug+w .;` This grants permission to all the files and folders in the directory. Read more [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34430011/7004388) @Musikero31