# Jenkins fails to fetch the repo some times

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am getting this error when I try to build my project in Jenkins.

```
Started by user jenkins
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/booking-widget-api
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://xxx@bitbucket.org/yyy/repo-name.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://xxx@bitbucket.org/yyy/repo-name.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://xxx@bitbucket.org/yyy/repo-name.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://xxx@bitbucket.org/yyy/repo-name.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:888)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1155)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1794)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://xxx@bitbucket.org/yyy/repo-name.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 8, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:  12% (1/8)           
remote: Compressing objects:  25% (2/8)           
remote: Compressing objects:  37% (3/8)           
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (4/8)           
remote: Compressing objects:  62% (5/8)           
remote: Compressing objects:  75% (6/8)           
remote: Compressing objects:  87% (7/8)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.        
remote: Total 8 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)        
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:405)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:886)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

First time when I get this error. I just give up for some time (a day). Then I build the project, it worked as normal and build successfully. Now again I am getting this error. Does any body face this kind of issue?

Comment: Not enough space on disk might be the reason. Also try to always wipe the workspace and clone a fresh repo every build.

Answer (score 6):

Stumbled upon this topic while searching for the same solution.

We have this Jenkins multi-branch pipeline which has been there for a long time. One day it started failing with the same errors.

```
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported
remote: Counting objects: 82, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (1/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:   3% (2/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:   5% (3/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:   7% (4/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:   9% (5/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  11% (6/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  12% (7/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  14% (8/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  16% (9/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  18% (10/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  20% (11/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  22% (12/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  24% (13/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  25% (14/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  27% (15/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  29% (16/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  31% (17/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (18/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  35% (19/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  37% (20/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  38% (21/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  40% (22/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  42% (23/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  44% (24/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  46% (25/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  48% (26/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (27/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  51% (28/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  53% (29/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  55% (30/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  57% (31/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  59% (32/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  61% (33/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  62% (34/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  64% (35/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (36/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  68% (37/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  70% (38/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  72% (39/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  74% (40/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  75% (41/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  77% (42/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  79% (43/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  81% (44/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  83% (45/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  85% (46/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  87% (47/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  88% (48/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  90% (49/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  92% (50/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  94% (51/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  96% (52/54)           
remote: Compressing objects:  98% (53/54)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.        
remote: Total 82 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)        
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:351)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:374)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:583)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:293)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

My colleague suggested to remove the `.git` from the Project Repository URL --- it worked!

We still haven't found the reason how it worked, but yeahh it does.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this error:
`error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects`
You may want to have a look at:
[Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)
Likely want to review some permissions.

Answer (score 0):

**Reconfigure Jenkins Job**

In our case the following helped:

- Turn off the job configuration for *Lightweight checkout*

Why it was working all the time with no change on jenkins / bitbucket / jenkins job - no idea.

This feature is described as follows:

> If selected, try to obtain the Pipeline script contents directly from
>   the SCM without performing a full checkout. The advantage of this mode
>   is its efficiency; however, you will not get any changelogs or polling
>   based on the SCM. (If you use checkout scm during the build, this will
>   populate the changelog and initialize polling.) Also build parameters
>   will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode. Only
>   selected SCM plugins support this mode.