# Git clone fails when in external drive

Tags: git, git-clone

I have an external drive which I would like to clone git repositories to. When I run git clone on the external drive I get the following error

```
Cloning into 'covid-19-data'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database /mnt/d/covid-19-data/.git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

However when I run git clone on my C drive it clones not problem. I can create a new file on the external drive from the command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)

Comment: `sudo git clone etc...`

Comment: How to deal with permissions is really not a programming question.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the system you're on, the file system of the remote drive, or the permissions involved on that drive.  I assume it's Windows and WSL, but you haven't said.

Comment: I am on windows using WSL1. The file system on the external drive is exFAT.