# Gitlab Pipeline in unable to Access terraform module with source in Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab

Here is what I am trying to do -

Repo A : Terraform Configurations files to create ec2 ( works fine )

Repo 2:

```
module "my-ec2-instances" {
    source = "git::https://gitlab.com/myawsmodules/my-ec2?ref=main"
    project_name = "module-test"
    env_name = "test"
}
```

Next,

I added module repo to the list of allowed projects ( Settings->CICD->Token Access)

When I run the pipeline I am getting the following error

> Error: Failed to download module
> │
> │   on main.tf line 1:
> │    1: module "my-ec2-instances" {
> │
> │ Could not download module "my-ec2-instances" (main.tf:1) source code from
> │ "git::[https://gitlab.com/myawsmodules/my-ec2"](https://gitlab.com/myawsmodules/my-ec2%22): error downloading
> │ 'https://gitlab.com/myawsmodules/my-ec2': /usr/bin/git exited with 128:
> │ Cloning into '.terraform/modules/my-ec2-instances'...
> │ fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or
> │ address
> │

Comment: Hi, does this solve your question? [could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address on Gitlab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68889098/2074608)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I checked the link. I am doing this test in Gitlab IDE. Do you think I should try the solution by adding in the pipeline ?

Comment: I created a personal_token, created an gitlab environment variable and made the following to my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```git config --global url."https://oauth2:${GITLAB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf https://gitlab.com
terraform init```