# git push: "error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects"

Tags: git

Yeah, I know, this thing has been on here before, I've seen the questions.
git push gives me this:

> error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

I have just one question: Is this error regarding the local or the server-side repository database?

And why am I the only one getting this error among the developers?

(I'm asking this question because my server guy doesn't want to believe me that this is a server-side problem)

---

Alright, here's the long version:

Two users have pulled a rep into their workspace.

1. User 2 pushes some change.
2. User 1 changes something, commits, then pulls the change of User 2 to be merged.
3. User 1 tries to push, but gets this:

   git.exe push --progress  "origin" dev:dev

   Counting objects: 18, done.
   Compressing objects: 100% (10/10)
   Writing objects: 100% (10/10)
   Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 870 bytes, done.
   Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
   error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

   fatal: failed to write object
   error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
   To git@XXX:twf
   ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (n/a (unpacker error))
   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@XXX:twf'

   git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error pushing to GitHub - insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918524/error-pushing-to-github-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-reposi)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I didn't get your question, but... you're right, of course, there are several questions asked here about exactly the same. Let's check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918524/error-pushing-to-github-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-reposi), for example:

> Usually this problem is caused by wrong user and group permissions on
>   your **git servers file-system**.

UPDATE: anyway, it's actually quite easy to make the check who is to blame - your local environment or the server's one. Let some other developer (*but not user 2*!) to make exactly the same update that you did (update the same files you did; it won't be too hard, considering your report), then try to `git push` these updates from his/her machine.

Comment: Yes, I do need something more persuasive.

Comment: I added a few more details to the question... Maybe that helps.

Comment: Updated my answer: if the method given there won't help, I don't know what'll help. )

Comment: We've already got it fixed, thank you! It seems that it was indeed a server-side error, but other the server admin, being a developer himself, couldnt reproduce the behaviour with his local repository. Sort of strange. But oh well....