# Git: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database

Tags: git, ubuntu

I have git error: "insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database" every time I make "git push origin master".
I tried solution described here: http://parizek.com/2011/05/git-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-database-objects/ but it works only until next time...
Is there some permanent solution?

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.19 KiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code'

$ git config core.sharedRepository true

$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.19 KiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code'

$ sudo chmod -R g+ws *
$ sudo chgrp -R andrey *
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.19 KiB, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: <Repository /git/p/project/code.git> refresh queued.
To ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code
   acd82d2..f401c90  master -> master
```

This is Ubuntu I use: 12.04.1, and git: 1.7.9.5

Comment: Why are you doing this? Use github or gitorious or a solution which has already solved this problem.

Comment: It possible use these tools if I store code in source forge?

Comment: @Stefan Kendall: Perhaps the user is using a company-internal Git project, and he or his company does not want to move their code to an external service they have no control over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Error pushing to GitHub - insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918524/error-pushing-to-github-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-reposi)", you need, in addition of the git config setting, to:

- first set the `umask` for all your repos: `umask 002` (so on your server side)
- then set the git group to `rw` as mentioned in your solution, still on the server side.

Comment: OK, it seems to work. I put umask command in .bashrc file also.

Comment: What does that `umask 002 /var/git/repositories` do? `umask` shell builtin doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 8):

That usually happens when someone commited to git while booing root. 
The .git/* files created in that process are protected from external change.

```
chmod -R 777 .git
```

is a fast fix.