# Can you git push origin to remote folder owned by root via ssh?

Tags: git, ssh

I have two computers at my house.  One is a server that holds my git init repository.  I cloned the repository on my desktop (git clone via ssh).  I made some changes and tried to push them to origin master but it won't allow me to write the files...  I read many articles and created groups and permissions and still I get this?  Any help or advice would be very much appreciated.

```
sudo git push origin dev 
[sudo] password for localuser: 
remoteuser@192.168.0.5's password: 
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 629 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects



fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To remoteuser@192.168.0.5:/var/www/apps
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'remoteuser@192.168.0.5:/var/www/apps'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770410/git-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-database?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Please show what exactly did you do about "created groups and permissions"