# Git permissions error started happening for seemingly no reason

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)

I've been doing some updates to a file, committing to a remote repo, then pulling changes from repo to a working copy i'm using as a staging site. I've made a couple of commits and pulled them this morning with no problem, but I just got the following error: `error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects` - permissions on the file i'm committing (and the directory i'm pulling changes to) look correct, so i'm not sure where this issue could have come from - any suggestions?

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab

Comment: Check your umask: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9073536/6309

Comment: Had some directories in .git/objects owned by root, so chowned to www-data and all fine now - thanks for the pointers

Comment: Can someone add the correct solution as answer to this question and author accept it ?

Comment: Solution i used specifically was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7849784/1176822

Comment: @bsod99 You can post answers to your own questions