# Git unpack error

Tags: git, version-control

When I try to push, I receive this output/error:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 322 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

As a preface, I have read, and attempted the fix in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918524/error-pushing-to-github-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-reposi). Unlike in that thread, though, my output makes no mention of permissions. As a result, the fix did not work.

Does anyone have any advice as to how to go about trouble-shooting this? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, try to isolate where the problem is occurring -- clone a fresh copy of the remote and see if you're able to push a change from there. If the error goes away, it's likely there's a corruption problem with the repo you were pushing. If it remains, then the problem is likely with the remote repo or the server hosting it.

Comment: Thanks @cjc343. Unfortunately, this is a fresh clone. I don't have access to the server, but the server admin did a push from his remote repo with no issues. Any idea how I could do some testing from my side, to isolate the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running `git repack remote/origin/master` and pushing again? If you run `git push -v` do you get any additional info?

Comment: @cjc343 - Unfortunately, no and no. I tried `git repack` which went through, but didn't go anything. And `git push -v` did not provide any additional info.

Comment: Is the server admin able to push using your account or an account configured with equivalent permissions? E: `git log` is showing you local commits.

Comment: @cjc343 - He used his own account. How can I check the permissions of my account? Further, how do I know my account name?

Comment: You'll likely need his assistance. If you look at the output of `git remote -v` you'll see URLs typically in the format user@server:repo if the user@ part is different than what he's used, the account may have different permissions. Alternatively, a single account can be used with multiple public keys while providing different levels of access via something like gitolite.

Comment: @cjc343 - I think we're all using the same account. All it shows is origin  http://git@panther.foo.edu/git/aa_code.git (fetch)
origin  http://git@panther.foo.edu/git/aa_code.git (push)

Comment: If you sent the admin a public key for which you have the private key, your permissions may still differ from the administrator's. The only other thing I can think of to test is whether the admin is able to push your changes given your copy of the repo you're trying to push. Either way, you'll need his assistance to check, and I'll likely be out of further troubleshooting steps to try.