# Can't push to git repository as normal user

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions, gitlab

There are a couple good posts on this subject, but I am not sure if they apply to my circumstances.

[Error pushing to GitHub - insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918524/error-pushing-to-github-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-reposi)

[Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)

When performing a push as a normal user, I receive the following error:

```
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to
    repository database ./objects
```

Note that I can push if I am logged on the local machine as root.  I see from the below that the origin is `git@easybbb.com:root`  I don't know if it matters, but the remote repository I am trying to push to is hosted by me using GitLab.

The local git directory is 0775 and belongs to group "www", I've executed `chmod -R g+rwxs /var/www/` to ensure that new files are of group "www", the normal user that is trying to push belongs to group "www", and I've executed `git config core.sharedRepository group`.

How do I fix this error?

```
git push origin master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 487 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To git@easybbb.com:root/bidjunction.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@easybbb.com:root/bidjunction.git'

git remote -v
origin  git@easybbb.com:root/bidjunction.git (fetch)
origin  git@easybbb.com:root/bidjunction.git (push)
```

Comment: You have no privileges on the server you are pushing on. Maybe the user does not exist.

Comment: delete your local repo and --clone the repo again. thats a  quick fix else try git push --all

Comment: @eddwinpaz.  Turned out I only had the original user configured on GitLab which was "root".  I've since created a new user.  This user is different than a Linux user, right?  I have a Linux user called "git" which GitLab uses to access Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do regarding the many similar questions.  The key is "remote: error: ".  The problem is the remote repository (GitLab which is similar to GitHub).  Making all associated files owned by git solved the problem.