# Git And Sudoers Sources Errors

Tags: git, sudoers

I have always permission error when pushing to Git. I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918524/error-pushing-to-github-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-reposi).

After applying this commands for specific git repo:

```
sudo chgrp -R mygroup *
```

I have this error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by gid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Why I have this error? What did I do wrong? What is the relation between `sudo chgrp -R mygroup *` and sudoers?

Comment: We have to switch assign our permissions to each other in every push!. But I want to know how sudo chgrp -R mygroup * could change the sudoers?

Comment: Are you sure you did the `chgrp` command in the right directory? Have a look at `ls -l /etc/sudoers` I guess the group is wrong. While you are at it, look at `ls -l /etc` and see if more harm was done.

Comment: with `groups` command I have found the group name and then `sudo chgrp -R mygroup *`

Comment: @DjangoLady Yes, but where have you done that? Did you look at the output of my above commands (the first one?) Check the group column.

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 root developers  1253 Aug 20 09:39 passwd   (but this is not the time that I have apply the command)

Comment: @DjangoLady, that does not look good. Somebody (if not you, or the changes in git repository) changed the group on the wrong files. I can't really help you from here, but this is very hard to fix (correctly and completely) again.