# Can't push changes to remote repo using gitbash windows

Tags: git, git-bash

I tried searching for a fix of this kind of issue but all of them won't work.
This error happens yesterday after changing to a new server.

When pulling updates, it works as it should but when I push changes the error below appears.

```
ERROR:

Counting objects: 8, done. Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done. Writing objects: 100% (8/8),
989 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to
repository database ./objects remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6448326/6309) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6494913/6309) [that error message](https://coderwall.com/p/8b3ksg/git-repository-failed-to-push-some-refs) points to a `chmod` and `git config core.sharedRepository group` to be done in the bare git repo *on the server side*.

That would be coherent with the fact you have changed server recently.

Comment: I'll try this one.  And be back later.