# Problem with git reset on rolling back to the previous commit

Tags: git, reset

I accidentally committed the huge unwanted folder and pushed it to master in git. And i had one more commit after that. so its like this

A - B - C - D

C -  is the problematic commit

After realizing the mistake i used the command

```
git reset --hard <sha1-commit-id-of-B>
```

and

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```

to rollback to the B. It was fine, but the size of the repo is still same. i was confused. how can i get rid of the unwanted files(permanently), so it wont appear on the git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you move the branch pointer back in this way, `git` doesn't immediately garbage-collect the objects that are now no longer referenced.  This is a good thing - it means, for example, that if you mistakenly do a `git reset --hard`, then you can recover the old commits easily, typically by using the `reflog` to find the object names of those commits, and creating a branch from one of them.  If you really want to garbage collect immediately to reclaim the space, you can do:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

However, one almost never needs to do this...

Comment: thanks mark, that's all i needed. Its a relief that  i dont need to garbage collect it manually, i ll let git do it the gc.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch, but on your own risk!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo/1905159#1905159