# Why does git run auto-packing on every push to our repo?

Tags: git

The last few days, each and every push to our git repository has caused auto-packing on the server.

The output on the client when this happens:

```
~pdr git:master ❯❯❯ git push origin master
Counting objects: 44, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 4.67 KiB, done.
Total 27 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
```

The packing happens on the server, and ps shows these git commands at work:

```
git      23252  0.0  0.0  68520   552 ?        S    15:21   0:00 sshd: git@notty  
git      23253  0.0  0.0   9660   540 ?        Ss   15:21   0:00 git shell -c git-receive-pack 'repositories/pdr.git'
git      23254  0.0  0.0  16644  2136 ?        S    15:21   0:00 git receive-pack repositories/pdr.git
git      23258  0.0  0.0   9660   624 ?        S    15:21   0:00 git gc --auto --quiet
git      23261  0.0  0.0   9660   504 ?        S    15:21   0:00 git repack -d -l -q -A
git      23262  0.0  0.0   4104   376 ?        S    15:21   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/git-core/git-repack -d -l -q -A
git      23275  267 92.2 9569724 3742468 ?     Sl   15:21  23:07 git pack-objects --keep-true-parents --honor-pack-keep --non-empty --all --reflog --unpack-unreachable --local -q --delta-base-offset /home/git/repositories/pdr.git/objects/.tmp-23262-pack
```

I have run a manual "git gc" followed by a "git fsck" on the server. No error messages, but on the next push it started auto-packing again.

This is on a server running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS with Git 1.7.0.4.

Comment: I recon the question is: "Why?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does "Auto packing the repository for optimum performance mean"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633981/what-does-auto-packing-the-repository-for-optimum-performance-mean)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392155/why-does-git-run-git-gc-auto-on-every-merge. This may be a duplicate of that, in fact.

Comment: @drvdijk "why is this happening on every push" is not the same as "what does auto packing a repo mean".

Comment: The question is indeed "Why?" :)

Comment: @patrickvacek I am not running on windows, and none of the commands have given any error commands. Not on client, not on server.

Comment: @drvdijk The OP in the post you link to never replied, so I don't know what his issue was. I have let all gc/repack commands complete, and it still triggers on every push.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Git decides whether to auto gc [based on two criteria](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L157):

1. Are there too many packs? (Literally, are there [more than 50 files](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L124) with `.idx` in `.git/objects/pack`?)
2. Are there too many loose objects? (Literally, are there [more than 27 files in `.git/objects/17`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L102)?)

If for some reason Git is not able to merge the pack files or remove the loose objects in that directory, it will think it needs to auto-gc again next time.

I would check the contents of the two directories cited above to see if the (default) criteria are met and see if the criteria change after the re-packing.

Some reasons for failure to complete the process might be:

- some sort of permissions problem
- unreachable objects that are ignored by Git's garbage collection or not pruned by default due to their youth
- insufficient disk space to complete the gc (the repack)
- insufficient memory to complete the gc (the repack)
- objects too large to fit in a specified pack size (see `git config pack.packSizeLimit` which defaults to unlimited but may be overridden by the user)

You should also ensure of course that the gc related tunable parameters haven't been set unreasonably by looking at:

```
git config -l | grep gc
```

For some other details, see the Git SCM book on [Git Internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery).

Comment: There are no loose objects, but there are 346 packs... No gc options have been set, but because of a puny server with 4GB ram we have set pack.windowmemory=50m and pack.packsizelimit=100m. And we have a huge repo because we did the mistake of adding big binary files when we started out with git.

Comment: "Unreasonable tuning parameters" was indeed the problem. I increased pack.packsizelimit to 500m, and after a repack I have 27 .idx files in objects/pack and the the repo behaves. Thanks for helping.

Comment: packSizeLimit was set to 10m for me. Changing it to 2g resolved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone with too many loose objects: Use `git gc --prune=3days` to remove them for everything older than 3 days. (Default is 2 weeks otherwise.)