# Why does git keep telling me it's "Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance"?

Tags: git, background-process, packing

**Note**: I **don't** think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633981/what-does-auto-packing-the-repository-for-optimum-performance-mean), which is talking about a non-background pack which *hangs* git *with a subtly different error message*.

---

In one of my git repositories, each time I invoke (for example) `git fetch`, git prints:

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
```

It appears to print this every time if I do a `git fetch` repeatedly, even when there are no changes and nothing for `git fetch` to do. This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It also seems to happen with other network operations, such as `git push` and `git pull`.

The command returns back to the prompt instantly with no further output, and I cannot find any git process running on my machine. It seems to happen only with this repository, and only on this machine. `git config -l | grep gc` returns nothing.

What can I do to diagnose or fix this problem?

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.0.1
```

I am using OS X 10.9.

Comment: It looks like the same problem as the question you linked, but just happening fast enough to not appear to hang.

Comment: Also [possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925471/why-does-git-run-auto-packing-on-every-push-to-our-repo)

Comment: Trengot, I don't think so. The error message is subtly different - it mentions "the background".

Answer (score 217, accepted):

I found the solution from the second comment you provided, Trengot, thanks. It turns out that I had some dangling blobs, which were in `.git/objects/17` and hence triggering the packing:

```
$ git fsck
dangling blob d9ff0aeac4aa8b4e0907daed675ebf60278bc977
dangling blob dbff2d073741f9775c815d4a3c623736af224dad
dangling blob e1ffbab1c5b985cd1cd3bc0281075ea2ed80744a
dangling blob fdff59878ccb3a75689f4acca615cfb635288774
```

This cleaned them up:

```
$ git gc --prune=now
```

Be aware, as per Henrik's comment below, this may be a little dangerous. Take care!

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work for me. Be aware that `--prune=now` is a little bit dangerous. By default, `--prune` will keep 2 weeks of dangling blobs, meaning that if you accidentally did an incorrect rebase 5 minutes ago, or removed a branch yesterday, you can recover. Once you run this command, you lose all dangling blogs until right now – not 2 weeks ago. Also, it [seems](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) like you should never run it while performing other Git commands in another terminal, or your repo can become corrupt.

Comment: It never occurred before. for me worked by 'git clean -fd'. strange but It might be because of untracked files.