# Measure / count objects in Git to see whether I am close to auto-packing

Tags: git

I would like to measure / count objects in git to see whether I am close to auto-packing, I think it can be done trivially by counting files in .git/objects/..., but I am not sure.

Here is the story:

For a couple of days now, my git repo is auto-packing itself whenever I push to it. (The git repo lives on a USB memory stick, therefore the auto-packing is awfully slow and I have cancel it after 30 minutes or so)

it is the same problem as:

[What does "Auto packing the repository for optimum performance" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633981/what-does-auto-packing-the-repository-for-optimum-performance-mean)

> I'm having a problem with my git repo. For the last couple of days whenever I do a push to the server I get this message: "Auto packing the repository for optimum performance"

In that same thread I found the solution:

> To disable for one project:
>
> cd your_project_dir
>
> git config gc.auto 0
>
> To disable globally:
>
> git config --global gc.auto 0

That solved my problem for that particular repo...

...but I have got many more git repo's on my memory stick and I would like to know a way to measure if any of my other git repos is close to auto-packing

I found:

[Why does git run auto-packing on every push to our repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925471/why-does-git-run-auto-packing-on-every-push-to-our-repo)

> Git decides whether to auto gc based on two criteria:
>
> Are there too many packs? (Literally, are there more than 50 files with .idx in .git/objects/pack?)
>
> Are there too many loose objects? (Literally, are there more than 27 files in .git/objects/17?)

My question is almost answered, but I would simply like to have confirmation that I understand correctly: How can I measure / count loose objects to see if I am close to auto-packing ? -- is it (as suggested in the above answer) literally counting files in .git/objects/17 and compare to the hard limit of 27,

-- or maybe it is counting all files in .git/objects/01, .../02, .../03, etc... and comparing the average to a soft limit defined in git config global ?

-- even if it is trivial, is there a git command that counts objects in .git/objects/17 ? -- is there a git command that returns the hard limit of 27 ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer at [Why does git run auto-packing on every push to our repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925471/why-does-git-run-auto-packing-on-every-push-to-our-repo) is still valid. As you can see in the source code of the latest release of git (2.10.2), [this is the function `need_to_gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.10.2/builtin/gc.c#L194,L217) that decides whether gc is run.

- Is the option `gc.auto` is set to 0 or negative?
- Are there [`too_many_packs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.10.2/builtin/gc.c#L160,L181): is the option `gc.autopacklimit` (default 50) positive and less than the number of packs (`*.idx` files in `.git/objects/pack`)?
- Are there [`too_many_loose_objects`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L83,L122): is the option `gc.auto` (default 6700) positive, and is the number of loose objects in `.git/objects/17` (it looks only in this directory; doesn't count all and take average or max or anything like that) greater than `({gc.auto} + 255)/256)`?

So that's where the number 27 comes from: it's the floor of (6700 + 255)/256. You can increase it by increasing `gc.auto`. You can get the equivalent of this number 27 with the git command `git config --get gc.auto` but that only works if the option has been explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to measure / count objects in git to see whether I am close to auto-packing

Note that, as an indicator, Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) will help, since the "git pack-objects" command learned to report the number of objects it packed via the `trace2` mechanism.

See [commit 9ed8790](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ed8790282865fbd20825ac130650cf6b1a8818d) (11 Apr 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3d67555](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d67555744e6d4fbbc52b0a67c4b630c5d319bc2), 08 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `pack-objects`: write objects packed to `trace2`
>
> This is useful when investigating performance of pushes, and other times when no progress information is written (because the pack is written to stdout).

See [`Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/api-trace2.txt) for more on `trace2`, introduced in [commit ee4512e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee4512ed481a126dadd33334186e0e759d7f2f47) in Feb.2019 for Git 2.22.

Comment: See more at [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309)