# Even when I push to remote, gc doesn't appear to run

Tags: git, garbage-collection

According to [an answer of “How often should you use git-gc?”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30247544/877703), `git gc` is run automatically every time you push to remote.

I commented on the answer but never got a response, so I’m asking here.

> I have unreachable commits in my tree (as a result of `git commit --amend`). This can be verified with `git log --reflog`. I pushed a branch to the remote repository and checked my tree again; the unreachable commits were still there. Apparently `git gc` was not run when this push happened.
>    … ?

Example:

```
$ git commit -m 'commit A'
$ git commit -m 'commit B'
$ git commit -m 'commit C'
$ git commit --amend -m 'commit D'
$ git commit -m 'commit E'
$ git commit -m 'commit F'
$ git push origin master
$ git log --reflog
```

```
* commit F (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
* commit E
* commit D (an amendment of C)
|
| * commit C
|/
* commit B
* commit A
```

When I push master to remote and run `git log --reflog`, commit C is still visible. This is still the case even if commit C is over 30 days old. I thought `git push` automatically runs `git gc`, and I thought `git gc` deletes the unreachable commits (in this case, C). Am I missing something?

Comment: Which repo are you expecting the commit to disappear from? `git push` will do `git gc` _on the remote repo_.

Comment: Also you can have heisenbug problems here: I believe reflog itself can represent a reference to the commit.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on the internet I found that according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17930609/5226835) answer on stackoverflow:

---

Git decides whether to auto gc [based on two criteria](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L157):

1. Are there too many packs? (Literally, are there [more than 50 files](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L124) with `.idx` in `.git/objects/pack`?)
2. Are there too many loose objects? (Literally, are there [more than 27 files in `.git/objects/17`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.0.4/builtin-gc.c#L102)?)

If for some reason Git is not able to merge the pack files or remove the loose objects in that directory, it will think it needs to auto-gc again next time.

---

However based on what [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316387) book says we have that:

> Git runs garbage collection automatically if:
>
> • There are too many loose objects in the repository
>
> • A push to a remote repository happens
>
> • After some commands that might introduce many loose objects
>
> • When some commands such as git reflog expire explicitly request it

but I couldn't find **WHICH** commands are actually triggering this command anywhere. My guess is that is not really defined by the specifications and it does depend on the implementation/version you are using.

Anyway this book states clearly that you are right and after a push this command is triggered, however I couldn't find a confirmation for this anywhere.

I instead found a in the `git push` documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push-codegitpushorigindevmastercode) an example where it says that unless you run a `git gc` after your `git push` there will be unreachable commits.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that commits will be garbage collected immediately, but git will actually wait [30 days by default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) until it removes unreachable commits. This behaviour can be altered with the `gc.reflogExpireUnreachable` configuration setting.

Comment: but even unreachable commits over 30 days old are still not being deleted. I have commits over a year old still left in the repo! sorry, should have mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to remove unreachable commits from the local repo

```
 git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 \                                                                      (release-branch|✔) 17:49:31
    -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc "$@"
```

See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo). I suspect your problem stems from `git reflog` itself keeping a reference to unreachable commits (thus making them "reachable")