# Remove stale commits from Git

Tags: git, commit, reset

I have made some test commits (to test a commit hook) and always reset the index to my last normal commit. Now these stale commits still exist:

```
> git reflog
fcdabf7 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to fcdabf7e01845d6f000fc3cef2edc999c57a7e29
5c97564 HEAD@{1}: commit: t
fcdabf7 HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to fcdabf7e01845d6f000fc3cef2edc999c57a7e29
ae52246 HEAD@{3}: commit: t
fcdabf7 HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to fcdabf7e01845d6f000fc3cef2edc999c57a7e29
c58aeef HEAD@{5}: commit: t
fcdabf7 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to fcdabf7e01845d6f000fc3cef2edc999c57a7e29
3a2cc3b HEAD@{7}: commit: test
```

How can I remove them? And for technical understanding: If I leave them alone, will they be pushed to the upstream repo if I do a push?

Comment: Afaik you will only push the commits that are reachable through the branch you push. If it is not in `git log`, it's not pushed. Also try `git gc` to clear unreachable commits.

Comment: I tried `git gc --aggressive --prune=2015-01-01` but that didn't remove them from reflog.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1904860/11343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commits referenced by the reflog entries are not dangling per se. To clear the reflog,

```
git reflog expire --expire=0 --all
```

afterwards which `git prune` can be used to remove the - now-dangling - commits.

Comment: That works and `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` removed the commits. Of course that means I lose the reflog everytime I do this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need not worry about the dangling commits making their way into a remote repository. They will not be pushed, and will generally be cleaned up in due course.

However, if you want to clear off such dangling object, try running:

```
git gc --prune=now
```