# How can I get rid of "Lost heads"?

Tags: git, smartgit

In my first attempt to do something with git I used GitHub for Windows. As it is simple and quite primitive tool I decided to try SmartGit. As I was looking around I discovered I have leftovers over my tests - something called "lost heads". How can I get rid of this garbage? It seemed that

```
git gc --prune=now
```

or something similar should work, but nothing changed. I tried googling, but everybody was trying to do reverse thing - restore lost commits from lost head or something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html), `git gc` will not garbage collect files which are referenced through the 'reflogs' (`.git/logs/<ref-name>` files in your repository). These HEADs are exactly what SmartGit/Hg displays and when you remove these logs, the unreferenced commits should be collected by a `git gc --prune=now`.

**Warning** Unless there is no really good reason to completely get rid of these commits (like removing sensitive data), you shouldn't do that -- maybe some time later your might be interested in exactly one of these commits. At least, reclaiming disk space is no good reason, in my opinion.

Comment: reclaiming disk space is not my reason (my git repository takes less than 0,01% of available space) - I want to get rid of "aaaeaeae test 2626" hanging everywhere.

Comment: After some time it's difficult to find my commit when I have hundreds of them. That would be valid reason for me.

Comment: @pevik, if many lost heads make the Log confusing, just uncheck the option and only when needed recheck again.

Comment: @mstrap, and is there any way how to do it with plain git (not in SmartGit)?

Answer (score 0):

this will remove more than just `git gc --prune=now`:

```
git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 \
-c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc "$@"
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14728706/1069083