# git branch -d <branchname> throws error: branch <branchname> not found

Tags: git, git-branch

When I type `git branch`, I get

```
* master
localbranch
```

But when I try to remove the branch, `git branch -d localbranch`, I get a not found error:

```
error: branch 'localbranch' not found.
```

I have also tried to force the delete with `git branch -D localbranch`, but it is giving me the same error.

The branch was corrupted and I did the following procedure, [Git repository corrupt (incorrect header check; loose object is corrupt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725925/git-repository-corrupt-incorrect-header-check-loose-object-is-corrupt), to remove the corrupted files. But now I cannot delete the branch.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Branches are stored as files containing the SHA they point to. Try deleting the file for this branch, named `localbranch`, from the `.git/refs/head/` directory within your project:

```
rm .git/refs/heads/localbranch
```

Comment: Note that if this branch exists on the remote server as well (though the branch name doesn't suggest so), you could use `git push origin :branchname` to do that.

Comment: that file would only exist if the branch refs were unpacked, it would be better to do a git command that explicitly referenced `refs/heads/localbranch` without using the `.git` directory

Comment: @AndrewC Since this is a local branch, can we assume that it would be unpacked? Also, OP clearly mentioned that `git branch -d localbranch` didn't work for him, so I am curious what local command would work here... Did you mean to try `git branch -d refs/heads/localbranch`?

Comment: @AndrewC `git branch -d refs/heads/localbranch` doesn't work either.

Comment: create a branch with `git branch localname` verify it with `ll .git/refs/heads/localname` run `git gc` then try the `ll` again

Comment: I would recommend `git update-ref` and only muck around in the .git directory as a last resort noting that branches might be found in `.git/packed-refs`

Comment: Perfect! I found & deleted my problem branch under `.git/refs/remotes/origin` since it was a remote branch that didn't exist remotely nor locally but was still falsely showing up in `git branch -a`.

Answer (score 14):

In some cases the branch contains characters that do not display in the terminal window so I needed to go the repository directly.

My Git for Windows ended up in this state:

```
$ git branch -l
  master
* next
  my-topic-branch
```

But removal failed

```
$ git branch -D my-topic-branch
error: branch 'my-topic-branch' not found.
```

Showing the contents of the heads directory showed the branch name was more complicated...

```
$ ls -al .git/refs/heads
total 7
drwxr-xr-x 1 112802 197121  0 Oct 11 13:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 112802 197121  0 Jul 11 14:30 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 112802 197121 41 Oct  4 12:39 ''$'\302\222''my-topic-branch'
-rw-r--r-- 1 112802 197121 41 Sep 15 15:23 master
-rw-r--r-- 1 112802 197121 41 Oct 11 13:05 next
drwxr-xr-x 1 112802 197121  0 Jul 12 13:28 origin/
```

And I could successfully delete the full name

```
$ git branch -D ''$'\302\222''my-topic-branch'
Deleted branch my-topic-branch (was efbc2fa).
```

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to delete the branch not only from `.git/refs/head/` but also from `.git\refs\remotes` Just throughly check for all refs in the .git folder. Then I just fixed up the git's memory with `git branch --unset-upstream` (since I was removing the branch that was an upstream)