# SourceTree Error: 'git status' failed with code 128: error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

[image: I got this error with open SourceTree]

```
$ git fsck --full
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: unable to unpack 06c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172 header
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: loose object 06c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172 (stored in .git/objects/06/c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172) is corrupt
```

also, try this, and remove the all corrupted objects. after removing objects i write this command,

```
$ git reset --hard
error: unable to read sha1 file of 3X/3X.Core/Resources/Resource.Designer.cs (d46f74436ae02ec61a659a8a487aee5747e2feda)
error: unable to read sha1 file of 3X/3X.Core/Resources/Resource.resx (63342162564404ccae4917489dc78ebb65075f8a)
error: unable to read sha1 file of 3X/3X.Web/Views/Job/ConfirmationAdvice.cshtml (ff39e42f5cf0e0703bd9dfe84a4b746ff91eea40)
error: unable to read sha1 file of 3X/3X.Web/Views/Job/Create.cshtml (3a97827faac6c62fd24f347dd0b0951c27c03751)
error: unable to read sha1 file of 3X/3X.Web/Views/Job/DataEntry.cshtml (89f381bafaeff53eeaf64a26d8c9608e9e86b6a1)
error: unable to read sha1 file of 3X/3X.Web/wwwroot/js/viewjs/Job/create.js (1b62c618c31add2ca28d107c1a49604492409ecf)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

and got above error

Comment: try doing it from command line

Comment: @DaniyalSyed I tried that but not works

Comment: what error are you getting on command line

Comment: @DaniyalSyed -- > $ git fsck --full
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: unable to unpack 06c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172 header
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
fatal: loose object 06c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172 (stored in .git/objects/06/c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172) is corrupt
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------I removed all these corrupt objects and also use "$ git reset --hard", this returns "fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'."

Comment: check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725925/git-repository-corrupt-incorrect-header-check-loose-object-is-corrupt

Answer (score 5):

Try with removing your index file which is in .git folder

**Windows System:**

```
del .git\index
git reset
```

**Linux System:**

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

And if you have deleted index file manually then you need to do

```
git reset
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be corrupted. Try removing this `.git/objects/06/c147f2771e280dfb4758c9a83b94346993d172`

If you are getting same error with another object try removing all those and fetch again.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. Do you have any other trick?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me
i opened my server and went to .git/ and downloaded index file from there then deleted the local .git/index file manually and replace the file with the downloaded index file

Answer (score 0):

Tried all answers and none worked with me.

Finally figured out that the problem is that you have probably configured your Source Tree repo to be located at repo_local_url/.git

The solution is to make it point at repo_local_url instead

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I accidentally removed the `git/objects` folder. When I restored it from the `Recycle Bin` it worked again.