# Git - I have an inflate data stream error, unable to unpack

Tags: git

Git - I have an inflate data stream error, unable to unpack.

I have to fix this issue because I have work in another branch that I don't want to lose.

I need to be able to switch from master to another branch and currently I cant do that.

I'm currently in my **master branch** and have the error below.

**Git bash error:**

```
$ git status
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 170e7e0b06043ee50bdd0228e8bd82b0ef86d29d header
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 170e7e0b06043ee50bdd0228e8bd82b0ef86d29d (stored in .git/obj
ects/17/0e7e0b06043ee50bdd0228e8bd82b0ef86d29d) is corrupt
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749070/1394393)? what things have you tried?

Comment: Just found the answer below