# How to cleanup git history?

Tags: git

I have this:

```
* [f037cb3] (HEAD, master, branch-01) More cleanup
* [9d3d167] Trying to cleanup
| *   [e524891] (refs/stash) On (no branch): Checkout 75d5bbe7e935eef26b88af304838c04abb60c629 at 7/5/14 12:31 A| |\
|/ /
| * [cf4235c] index on (no branch): 22c8c38 Before implementing blueprints
|/
* [22c8c38] Before implementing blueprints
* [3cff07c] Switched to Bootstrap
* [a4d5973] Added basic unit test
* [a14a6ab] Added 404 and 500 error pages
* [869bf35] Added user_id to stored session data
* [08dcf3b] Updated forms
* [9fc43b7] Added user registration
* [2e41a3c] Added database file to git
* [4eccb17] Renamed database file
* [e9820fc] Added user registration
* [02a2448] Most of the transition to SQLAlchemy is done. Commit just before adding forms.py
* [dcc0f56] Before switching to Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

How do I get rid of these two?

```
[e524891] (refs/stash) On (no branch): Checkout 

[cf4235c] index on (no branch): 22c8c38 Before implementing blueprints
```

Comment: So you don't need those changes?

Comment: No, it was a complete mess.  Nothing worked.  Don't need any of that, wills start a new branch and start over.  So, I'd like the tree to be clean.

Comment: Well, according to the tree - they don't belong to any branch. Just leave it as-is and GC will drop them one day.

Comment: Those two references are from running `git stash`.  To drop the stash without attempting to apply it anywhere, use `git stash drop`.  Be sure you really mean this!

Comment: Well, what's interesting is that I've never run `git stash`.  I'll try that and see what happens.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those commits are not references by any branch, one simple trick is to clone your repo.

The new clone should get a clean history: `master` commits only.

As [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592770/how-to-cleanup-git-history/24592816#comment38100861_24592816), you can run [`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc), but I prefer keeping the first repo as it is (in case I need to find some lost data back), and work with a new clone.

By having to run a `git gc --prune=now`, you might drop more than you intended.

You see other cleaning techniques in "[How to remove unreferenced blobs from my git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1904860/6309)".

Comment: ... or one could run `git gc` (with `--prune` == today)

Comment: tbh I'm not sure `today` will work, never tried that. But if it will - I've learnt something new today :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's enough to shove me in the right direction.