# Can't remove a blob from a Git repo

Tags: git, blob

I have a local-only repository which used to contain very large files (scans and some DB files). At some point I decided I'd remove the directory containing all those, and rewrite the history to eradicate the directory in question.

I ended up with a very light repo, but the .git directory still takes 1.3G of space. There is only one pack, and I identified at least one blob in this pack taking a lot of space.

I tried a lot of things to clean up the repo, including various summonings of git gc, but nothing works, not even git forget-blob. Git forget-blob tells me « not found in the repo history ».

At that point, I'm lost. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: some additional information which I find very bizarre. Git verify-pack shows me 3 very big files:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-5cc03e9fbdbdff4ce1bbeb43c55c3e17875f2bd7.idx| sort -k 3 -n | tail -3
4983118ae60be35299b153dc5850134329f6ddf0 blob   7336960 2000979 615935480
5c810dfffa6a033631596218c43a7360cf2aff10 blob   12455669 1197771 6330554
25012927d95cf3bd15f2a8cb30da2c4f4b988e82 blob   105476096 83834099 532101381
```

However, I cannot get any information on those blobs. How's that possible?

```
git rev-list --objects --all  | grep 250129
zsh: done       git rev-list --objects --all | 
zsh: exit 1     grep --color 250129
```

Comment: `forget-blob` is not a standard Git command, so it must be something you installed (perhaps from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41801085/1256452)?). If so, the linked script appears to have a bug, but the bug should leave the blob in there so that a second run of `git forget-blob` also pretends to remove it, in the case I'm thinking of.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in the script. I have edited my original question with additional information.

Comment: Ah, so you deleted the file using something other than the forget-blob script originally? It would help a lot if you included *exact commands* and their output (cut and paste the text, not screen-shots, if at all possible). I'm guessing now that the object is in fact not reachable in the pack, but without running `git repack -A -d` Git will not rebuild the pack to discard the unreachable object.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. Your comment is not on the right question. Care to answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566539/is-the-transparent-shadows-hack-for-beamer-blocks-broken ?  If you can't for some reason, I'll propagate your answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that have to be considered:

- Any revision from reflog is pointing to any of the previous revisions (before the rewrite)?
- Any stash object is pointing to any of the old revisions?
- Any remote branch is poiting to any of the old revisions?

In order to convince git to delete an object, there should be *no* pointers to it. Another thing to consider is that objects are saved in "packs". I remember that I once had to "explode" all the pack files I had (that is, get git to put all objects on the FS), then deleted the pack files and then I asked git to repack.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Check the part about "Removing objects". Hope that's good enough.