# delete openshift git/objects folder

Tags: git, openshift

I am trying to clean up openshift git repo. objects folder in .git seems huge. I can ssh into application and execute the commands

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

server is getting restarted while the command is being executed and the connection gets disconnected. The total size of objects folder is more than 3 GB for an application that should be less than 100 MB.
please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`git gc` alone can increase the size of your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1908476/6309).

I prefer:

```
git gc
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

The [reflog part can be used to remove unreferenced elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29203553/6309) and would come first:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: "Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Connection to prod-myDomain.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
Connection to prod-myDomain.rhcloud.com closed.   " Still get the same issue.