# GIT - Remove old reflog entries

Tags: git, purge, git-reflog

After a lot of rebasing a repository to our latest needs our reflog is full of commits and orphan branches. We reached the final state of our reorganization.

While there're branches and commits left with a lot of binary data the repository grew multiple times of its origin size we decided to purge all the old reflog entries and data.

I was digging in the manual but didn't get much smarter experimenting with [git-reflog expire](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog#git-reflog---expirelttimegt)

This is an example of the log (shortened)

```
-> <sha1> [development] ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
-> <sha1> [master] ...
-> <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
| <sha1-old> ...
-> <sha1-old> ...
```

As you can see below the master branch there is the old commits / branches stating the repository before the rebase.

We expect to clear the reflog to have the repository look like

```
-> <sha1> [development] ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
| <sha1> ...
-> <sha1> [master] ...
```

In order we expect to reduce the disk space used by the repository.

How can I accomlish that?

---

### Edit (2019-03-02 12:20)

Please do not mention to delete and re-clone the repository. This is not what I'm looking for.

---

### Edit (2019-03-02 12:30)

What I tried so far but what not worked

```
git reflog expire --expire=all
```

Nothing happened so I tried to be clever and invoked the garbage collector

```
git gc --aggressive
```

But bogus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove unreferenced blobs from my git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo)

Answer (score 45):

You need, specifically, the `--expire-unreachable` option:

```
git reflog expire --expire=90.days.ago --expire-unreachable=now --all
```

for instance.

#### What's the difference?

A *reflog* is a log for a reference (hence the name "reflog" :-) ).  A *reference* or [*ref*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_ref) is a name beginning with `refs/`, such as `refs/heads/master`, which is how the branch name `master` is really stored.  There is one extra reflog, for `HEAD` itself, which (since it doesn't start with `refs/`) is technically not a reference by the definition I linked in [the gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html), but then, the glossary definition goes on to say that there are some special references that don't start with `refs/`, so either they're confused, or I am. :-)

Anyway, the point of a reference is to store a hash ID (or in the case of the special `HEAD` reference, to store the name of another reference).  A hash ID is a value.  You can update a reference, which changes the stored value—so over time, the single name has taken on multiple different values.  There's the *current* value `master`, and then there is the one from one change ago, `master@{1}`, and from two changes ago, `master@{2}`, and so on.  (For consistency, you can spell the current value `master@{0}` if you like.)  This is all spelled out in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

The *reflog* is where Git keeps the *previous* values.  The reflog stores not only the previous value, but also the computer's clock-time when the value was changed—so Git can handle syntax like `master@{3.days.ago}` to find whichever entry, `master@{0}` or `master@{1}` or `master@{2}` or whatever, represents the value `master` had three days ago.  ("Three days" means 3 24-hour days: 72 hours and no minutes and no seconds ago, or precisely 259200 seconds ago.  If you changed `master` several times yesterday, you may need to be more precise than just `master@{yesterday}`.)

Anyway, so, suppose that the *current* value of `master` is `1234567...` (some big ugly hash ID), and that `master@{1}` is `8888888...` while `master@{2}` is `3333333...`.  So far, they all seem rather alike.  But they aren't necessarily so:

```
          1234567   <-- master
            /
...--o--8888888   [master@{1}]
      \
    3333333   [master@{2}]
```

The difference between `master@{1}` and `master@{2}` here—well, besides their values and the numbers inside the curly braces `{}`—the *important* difference to `git reflog expire` is that we can *find* `master@{1}` by starting from `master` (`1234567`) and working backwards.  If we start at `master` and go back one commit, we come to `master@{1}`.  If we go back another step we arrive at boring commit `o` whose number we don't even know; we skip right over commit `3333333`.

Specifically, in this case, `master@{2}` is *unreachable* from the current (`1234567`) value of `master`.  So its expiry is controlled by the `--expire-unreachable` argument, not by the `--expire` argument.

If you don't choose a particular value, `git reflog` will use the configured default, if you have configured one.  In the absence of a configured default, the *default* defaults are 90 days for reachable entries and 30 days for unreachable entries.  So:

```
--expire=90.days.ago --expire-unreachable=30.days.ago
```

is the default, unless you've changed your own defaults.  If you override *one* default on the command line, you leave the *other* default alone.

#### Rebase makes a lot of unreachables

Your question starts with an important point: you did a lot of rebasing.  Rebase works by *copying* commits, then switching branch names to use the new (and presumably improved) commits.  The old ones are still around, and are invariably unreachable from the new branch tip:

```
          A'-B'-C'  <-- branch
         /
...--o--o
         \
          A--B--C   [branch@{1}]
```

where `A--B--C` is the original chain (the old and icky commits) and `A'-B'-C'` are the shiny new copies that you want.  Since the connections always go backwards, the old ones are always unreachable from the new branch tips, even if they're reachable from some other references.