# remove single git reflog entry by hash/id

Tags: git, passwords, git-reflog, reflog

I committed sensitive data to a single file on my `main` branch. I never pushed it. I can change HEAD to point to the previous commit with `git reset HEAD^`, but the commit is still hanging around as `git reflog` shows.

How can I use the reflog hash/ID, to COMPLETELY remove/delete that commit?

Answer (score 3):

To remove a specific reflog entry, you can use:

```
git reflog delete HEAD@{X} # set X to the entry number listed in reflog
```

This is [documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). For removing all reflog history, or history older than a certain date, see this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49067898/184546).

Note, this removes the reflog entry *only*. For more information about completely removing the commit, see [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71714924/184546).

Answer (score 3):

You can't.<sup>1</sup>  There is no Git command that removes commits by hash ID or reflog entry.

You *can* however rest assured that if you use:

```
git push origin somebranch
```

and the set of commits reachable by traversing `somebranch`'s tip commit on backwards does not reach any of the reflog-entry-only commits, `git push` won't *send* **those** commits (the unwanted ones).  It will send only the commits listed by `git rev-list somebranch`, minus any commits that the receiving Git already has in the repository to which you're pushing.  So the fact that *you* still have the commits is not important.

The other things you can do—useful for the paranoid, a group in which I count myself sometimes—include:

- Clone your clone.  The resulting clone won't have the commits, so you can now safely run, in that clone:

  ```
  git remote add github ssh://git@github.com/myname/myrepo.git
  git push github origin/somebranch:somebranch
  ```

  to send the commits from your new clone's `origin/somebranch` (cloned from your old clone's `somebranch`) to your GitHub repository over at `github` (assuming your final target repository here is on GitHub; use other names and URLs as appropriate).
- Use `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=all`<sup>2</sup> or `git reflog delete --rewrite --updateref` to delete specific, or all unreachable, entries from some (specified) reflog or, with `--all`, all reflogs.  Note, however, that this does not delete the *commit*.
- Once the reflog entries are deleted, run `git gc --prune=now`.  *Be sure nothing else is active in the repository while this runs.*  If you have packed objects in a `.keep`-kept file, though, this won't get rid of them (but also note that `.keep` is something you would have had to manually create, so you probably do not have keep-files).

To verify that the commits are *really* gone, use `git show <hash-id>` or `git cat-file -t <hash-id>` for each hash ID.  Note that you will need to save the hash IDs somewhere, since there won't be any in-Git references to them (that's what allows `git gc` to remove them).

---

<sup>1</sup>*If*—this is a strong-ish condition but it may be met in your case—the commit has never been *packed*, you may be able to use `rm .git/objects/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` where the `xx`s are the hash ID, split up into first-two and remaining hexadecimal characters.  That's not a *Git* command and you have to **be very careful with this**; it's a good idea to copy or otherwise back up the repository first.  The *reflog entries* will still exist: they'll just become useless in that Git will barf up an error if you try to use them.

<sup>2</sup>This `all` should logically be `now`, and I believe `now` works, but it's what's listed in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Comment: wow, thanks for the deep answer. It sounds like the easiest thing for me to be assured things are cleaned up completely, and I don't make a mistake is to local clone (check reflog just to be paranoid), then push my commits, then delete the original clone's directory.