# Delete/Squash old commits while keeping the changes that they introduced

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash, git-history-rewrite

I'm trying to delete/squash a bunch of old commits that I don't want on my git history which were just made to put together code from multiple locations that were not using git (local folders from other programmers)

This is how the actual git history looks:

[Git history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odSZD.png)

What I want is to keep from A to N (newest) and either delete everything else or squash it into A.

I've tried two things

`git rebase -i --root -xtheirs`

and then mark from the root to 'A' to squash, but it ended changing some parts of code, which from what i've understood while researching is because of the old merge commits trying to re-do the merge commits.

I've also tried to use the param --rebase-merges but ended with wrong code too.

The other thing that I tried is to just do

`git rebase -i --root`

and delete everything between 'A' and root. But it also deleted all the code that were introduced in those commits.

As you might have guessed I'm pretty new to this kind of git commands so any explanation would be appreciated.

Other approaches are also welcome!

Edit: As @TTT noted in the comments, this is a duplicate of [How to remove all but last n commits from git history to save space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72995274/how-to-remove-all-but-last-n-commits-from-git-history-to-save-space), which has a good answer.

Comment: I believe the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72995274/184546) should work for you. (Just ignore all the side discussion about backup in that Q and A.)

Comment: That's perfect @TTT ! Many thanks! Also good to have the explanations of every command.

Comment: Note that it's `-Xtheirs` or `-X theirs` (uppercase X) - case is significant in Git!