# Git squash/combine old commits in a bare repository

Tags: git, git-history-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to remove certain old commits from a history for a bare git repo.
Normally, I would do `git squash` and squash everything besides `E` and `D` commits.
[image: old history]

That does not work for a bare repository

```
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree
```

When using more complex tools such as [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) I can skip commits from the history, but I would lose all the changes made by them (e.g. adding or modifying the file).

How to achieve this result for a bare repository?

[image: new history]

Comment: You need to reword your title and your question. It doesn't sound like you want to DELETE the commits, it sounds like you want to reorganzie and combine them.. Which is it.  Instead of asking about obscure ways to do a task, as how to do what it is you are actually trying to accomplish?  Sorry i missed your links.  could you provide them as text instead of images?

Comment: This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72995274/184546) provides a general solution for how to do this, but not necessarily in a bare repo. Note that for many things you don't even need to use the bare repo, since you can clone from the bare repo to another new repo, do what you want, and then push or force push back to the bare repo. You can also run garbage collection on the bare repo to clean it up later if desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the repository, perform your actions and then push the result.
If you don't want to do that, you could use the replace mechanism with grafts and `filter-branch` to make the grafts permanent.

**DISCLAIMER: This is a destructive operation and you could lose data if you are not careful. Best to have a backup of your full repo.**

```
git replace --graft D # make D a root commit
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all # make graft permanent
```

This leverages the fact that each commit references a full snapshot of your repository at any time (the `tree`). Removing the parent(s) from a commit makes it a root commit, but keeps its tree. If file1 and file2 first appeared in commits A and C respectively, they are already part of D's tree. Once you have the new root commit D1, its tree will still contain the two files. Since it is now the first commit, it will look like the files first appeared as part of this commit.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to make some commit a new root, but preserve the actual tree at that time. Let me try this approach.