How to revert the effect to .git after staging and unstaging a large file?
After mistakenly running git add <large_file>, the .git folder grows a considerable size. How to revert the effect so that it could look like the large file has never been added?
Here is what I've tried and got:

git add <large_file>: .git grows a considerable size
git rm --cached <large_file>: the large file is unstaged, but .git remains its size
git gc --aggressive: prints Enumerating cruft objects: 1, done., .git grows even more
Go to another folder, git clone <original_folder>: the new .git is the same size as in the last step


This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repository

For inspection purposes, running git hash-object <path/to/your/big/file> should output the same hash it used to store the blob. You'll find it in .git/objects/ in a folder named after the two first chars of the hash, the file name being the rest of the hash, all except the first two chars. That being said, it might be packed, in which case it would not be here. Maybe worth checking.

I believe you have to ask git gc to prune loose objects as well, try git gc --prune --aggressive and see if that helps.

You can try BFG Repo cleaner to remove mistakenly added files in Git.
From its official site:

Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' : $ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
Remove all blobs bigger than 50 megabytes : $ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M  my-repo.git
Replace all passwords listed in a file (prefix lines 'regex:' or 'glob:'
if required) with REMOVED wherever they occur in your repository
:
$ java -jar bfg.jar --replace-text passwords.txt  my-repo.git
Remove all folders or
files named '.git' - a reserved filename in Git. These often become a
problem when migrating to Git from other source-control systems like
Mercurial :
$ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders .git --delete-files .git  --no-blob-protection my-repo.git

Always make sure you have a backup of repository before using this tool for unintended deletion of files.
