# Remove file from git repository (history)

Tags: git, version-control, git-rewrite-history

(solved, see bottom of the question body)
Looking for this for a long time now, what I have till now is:

- http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/
  and
- http://progit.org/book/ch9-7.html

Pretty much the same method, but both of them leave objects in pack files... Stuck.
What I tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file_name'
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
rm -Rf .git/logs/
git gc
```

Still have files in the pack, and this is how I know it:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-3f8c0...bb.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -3
```

And this:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch file_name" HEAD
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --all &&  git gc --aggressive --prune
```

The same...

Tried `git clone` trick, it removed some of the files (~3000 of them) but the largest files are still there...

I have some large legacy files in the repository, ~200M, and I really don't want them there... And I don't want to reset the repository to 0 :(

SOLUTION:
This is the shortest way to get rid of the files:

1. check .git/packed-refs - my problem was that I had there a `refs/remotes/origin/master` line for a remote repository, delete it, otherwise git won't remove those files
2. *(optional)* `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/#{pack-name}.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -5` - to check for the largest files
3. *(optional)* `git rev-list --objects --all | grep a0d770a97ff0fac0be1d777b32cc67fe69eb9a98` - to check what are those files
4. `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file_names'` - to remove a file from all revisions
5. `rm -rf .git/refs/original/` - to remove git's backup
6. `git reflog expire --all --expire='0 days'` - to expire all the loose objects
7. `git fsck --full --unreachable` - to check if there are any loose objects
8. `git repack -A -d` - repacking
9. `git prune` - to finally remove those objects

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-purge-a-huge-file-from-commits-history-in-git/2158271 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history

Comment: zneak - my question is in the title.
gbacon - tried those, the files still remain in the pack file...

Comment: If you look at the article referenced in the duplicates, it shows how to compact your object store after the offending file has been removed.

Comment: You mean `git gc --aggressive --prune`  
Didn't work, it repacked everything, and the file is still there...

Comment: Does the blob in question show up in the output from `git fsck --full --unreachable`?

Comment: nope, git fsck --full doesn't return anything at all

Comment: This was a lifesaver. Mental note: always add potentially huge *.log files to .gitignore.  Went from a 800mb repo to 6mb after this.

Comment: step 2 and 3 in one

`for i in \`git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/#{pack-name}.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -5\` ; do git rev-list --objects --all | grep $(echo $i | sed 's/ .*//g') ; done`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I can't say for sure without access to your repository data, but I believe there are probably one or more packed refs still referencing old commits from before you ran `git filter-branch`. This would explain why `git fsck --full --unreachable` doesn't call the large blob an unreachable object, even though you've expired your reflog and removed the original (unpacked) refs.

Here's what I'd do (after `git filter-branch` and `git gc` have been done):

*1) Make sure original refs are gone:*

`rm -rf .git/refs/original`

*2) Expire all reflog entries:*

`git reflog expire --all --expire='0 days'`

*3) Check for old packed refs*

This could potentially be tricky, depending on how many packed refs you have. I don't know of any Git commands that automate this, so I think you'll have to do this manually. Make a backup of `.git/packed-refs`. Now edit `.git/packed-refs`. Check for old refs (in particular, see if it packed any of the refs from `.git/refs/original`). If you find any old ones that don't need to be there, delete them (remove the line for that ref).

After you finish cleaning up the `packed-refs` file, see if `git fsck` notices the unreachable objects:

`git fsck --full --unreachable`

If that worked, and `git fsck` now reports your large blob as unreachable, you can move on to the next step.

*4) Repack your packed archive(s)*

`git repack -A -d`

This will ensure that the unreachable objects get unpacked and *stay* unpacked.

*5) Prune loose (unreachable) objects*

`git prune`

And that should do it. Git really should have a better way to manage packed refs. Maybe there is a better way that I don't know about. In the absence of a better way, manual editing of the `packed-refs` file might be the only way to go.

Comment: Yey!!! I love you !
The problem was in packed-refs file, there was refs/remotes/origin/master from times I was backing it up on some server... once I removed it it all began to disappear... Thank you! (updating the question body with the full solution)

Answer (score 17):

I'd recommend using the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch` specifically designed for rewriting files from Git history. One way in which it makes your life easier here is that it actually handles *all* references by default (all tags, branches, stuff like refs/remotes/origin/master, etc) but it's also [10-50x](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsR1d5Zpes8HdER3VGU1a3dOcmVHMmtzT2dsS2xNenc) faster.

You should carefully follow these steps here: http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage - but the core bit is just this: download the [BFG's jar](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 6 or above) and run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --delete-files file_name  my-repo.git
```

Any file named `file_name` (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be will be *totally removed* from your repository's history. You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The BFG is generally much simpler to use than `git-filter-branch` - the options are tailored around these two common use-cases:

- Removing **Crazy Big Files**
- Removing **Passwords, Credentials** & other **Private data**

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Does this also clean private data from remote repos after pushing?

Comment: @ThomasLauria yup, the same cleaned refs are pushed to remote repos on  pushing - the instructions at http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage should cover it. If you have control over the remote repo, you can also run "git gc --prune=now --aggressive" on it after pushing to ensure dead objects are immediately removed from that also.

Comment: @RobertoTyley This can result in two commits that appear after each other in the history and that have the same tree (if one of these commits only added the deleted file(s)). Do you know an easy way to remove such commits from the commit history, as they seem artificial?

Comment: @RobertoTyley I think that concerns another issue. Only one repository is involved in the case I described. But `git filter-branch --prune-empty` seems to be the solution to my question (though using another tool, please let me know if the BFG Repo-Cleaner can do the same).

Answer (score 6):

I found this to be quite helpful with regards to removing a whole folder as the above didn't really help me: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data.

I used:

```
git filter-branch -f --force \
--index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch folder/sub-folder' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to get rid of a big file in the history, and the above answers worked, up to a point. The point is: they don't work if you have tags. If the commit containing the big file is reachable from a tag, then you would need to adjust the filter-branches command thusly:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat \
--index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch huge_file_name' -- \
--all --tags
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be covered by the `git obliterate` command in Git Extras (https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras).

```
git obliterate <filename>
```

Answer (score 2):

See: [How do I remove sensitive files from git’s history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/how-do-i-remove-sensitive-files-from-gits-history)

The above will fail if the file does not exist in a rev.  In that case, the '--ignore-unmatch' switch will fix it:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <filename>' HEAD
```

Then, to get all loose objects out of the repostiry:

```
git gc --prune='0 days ago'
```

Comment: Yep, tried this one, still have the files in the pack, and the size didn't change too much...

Comment: I just made a git sandbox and tried it.  No good here, either.  Let's see what I can figure out.

Comment: The one in the answer? :) It's the same as I posted, and it still leaves the file in the pack... try a git sandbox, doing git gc so it will pack the file, and then running this...

Comment: Oh, the loose objects?  See above.  I'd be inclined to just let them be garbage collected in two weeks (the default for gc); killing _all_ loose objects is like emptying the trash--I lose any opportunities to get back anything I accidentally deleted.

Comment: :) tried this one too... got rid of some of the files, but the biggest are still there...

Comment: Drats.  I thought that would do it.  Do the files exist in any other branches?

Comment: Have no other branches :) But I think that it might be that I moved the file from one dir to another once... I run the filter-branch on both paths, but that doesn't help...

Answer (score 2):

You have various reasons for a still large git repo size after `git gc`, since it [does not remove all loose objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106529/how-to-skip-loose-object-popup-when-running-git-gui/1108084#1108084).

I detail those reasons in "[reduce the git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)"

But one trick to test in your case would be to [**clone** your "cleaned" Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big) and see if the clone has the appropriate size.

(' "cleaned" repo ' being the one where you did apply the `filter-branch`, and then `gc` and `prune`)

Comment: Yep, tested it already, and tested it again now, it reduced repository by 2k :) and the files are still there...

Comment: What's weird is `git count-objects -v -> count: 0, size: 0, in-pack: 10021, packs: 1, size-pack: 244547, prune-packable: 0, garbage: 0`
but: `git clone test1 test2 -> Checking out files: 100% (8509/8509), done`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found a great [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) on github that explain step by step how to get rid of files you accidentally committed.

Here is a little summary of the procedure as Cupcake suggested.

If you have a file named `file_to_remove` to remove from the history :

```
cd path_to_parent_dir

git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch file_to_remove' \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged on Stack Overflow, because if the link breaks in the future, then the answer becomes useless. Please consider summarizing the relevant information contained in the link in your answer.