# remove filenames from specific path?

Tags: git-rewrite-history

I've been playing around with the BFG Repo-Cleaner tool in order to clean up the history of a git repo by removing (temporary / large) files from several places in the directory hierarcy...

i.e.
/root/test/a.txt
/root/test2/a.txt

Now i'd like to remove *all* references of the 'test/a.txt' but *keep* the /test2/a.txt version..

Is there any way to cleanly remove that using BFG? (as mentioned on https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)

Since the repo has a fairly large history ( 10K commits ) BFG really is *alot* faster than the other methods i've seen so far...

Comment: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm the developer of [The BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), and I'm glad you've been finding it useful and fast. Part of the special-sauce that makes the BFG so fast is that it's path-independent - so you can't say directly say something like `--delete /root/test/a.txt`. Adding some support for path-dependent action is something I'm thinking about, but I don't want it to adversely affect performance.

The key question when cleaning your repo is: What are you trying to achieve, out of these two options:

- Reduction in Git repository size
- Removal of private data

From your question, it sounds like your only aim is the first one, to reduce Git repository size. If `/root/test/a.txt` is fairly small- ie comparable in size to the rest of the legitimate files in your repository - you can't really use `--strip-blobs-bigger-than X` to get rid of it, as it would remove too many of your other regular files. But if that *is* the case, I would just relax, and let it go - it's not costing you much storage space compared to the entirety of your repo.

If `/root/test/a.txt` is big enough to bother you, you can probably just use `--strip-blobs-bigger-than X` to get rid of it - remember that The BFG protects all files in your current commit (or even more branches if you use `--protect-blobs-from <refs>`) - so legitimate big files that you're *currently* using won't get touched.

If you *really* want to get rid of this poor innocuous file, but ***don't*** want to filter on size, there are two BFG-supported options:

#### Use `--delete-folders test`

...which will delete the entire folder `/root/test/` (and all other folders called 'test'), but not `/root/test2/`. Not much use if there are other things in `/root/test/` that you want to keep.

#### Use `--strip-blobs-with-ids <blob-ids-file>`

...you have to look up all the Git blob-ids there have ever been for `/root/test/a.txt`, which you can do with a some git commands like this:

```
git log --format=%H -- /root/test/a.txt | xargs -IcommitId git rev-parse commitId:/root/test/a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! My example was indeed trivial, but the point came across! The fact is, in some projects path/filenames aren't unique. And thus 'simply' clearing by last nibble of the path won't suffice. The `--strip-blobs-with-ids`-method _should_ work though... Couldn't that be automated into a --strip-by-path ""... ? Ohwell :) Thanks anyway for the fast tool and quick solution!

Comment: @Roberto Tyley I've tried the to use the --strip-blobs-with-ids extracting the ids using "git log --format=%H -- /root/test/a.txt | xargs -IcommitId git rev-parse commitId:/root/test/a.txt" but I didn't work. BFG says "BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??". Thanks!

Comment: It'd be great of BFG could target certain folders as `filter-branch` can be much more complex than is needed. A separate "slow" option would be great!

Comment: The --strip-blobs-with-ids is not working for me at all.

Comment: Deleting a folder deletes all files contained in that folder, correct?

Comment: Can't we just pipe in a list of filenames (like the contents of the unwanted folder)?