# How to delete one folder / directory using BFG repo cleaner?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

How do I delete only one directory using BFG?

The help says:

`delete folders with the specified names (eg '.svn', '*-tmp' - matches on folder name, not path within repo)`

Which seems to mean that `--delete-folders "config"` will match all folders named config, anywhere in the repository.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here: [remove files from specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142986/remove-filenames-from-specific-path)

The author of BFG says it can't be done, unless you use a special command to dump all blobs for a given directory to a text file, and then use --strip-blobs-with-ids and provide that text file.

[UPDATE]
This doesn't work for me. I run the command:

`git log --format=%H -- cms/assets/ | xargs -IcommitId git rev-parse commitId:cms/assets/`

I get a list of 8 blob ids. I put those in text file, then I exec `bfg -bi ~/tmp/blob-ids`, and BFG exits saying: `BFG aborting: No refs to update - no dirty commits found??`