# How to rebase a `filter-branch` from a subproject on my main repository's subtree?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-rebase, git-subtree

#### How to rebase a `filter-branch` from a subproject on my main repository's subtree?

To me this is a normal operation to be performed with submodules. I would just to do a normal rebase as described here: [Rebasing everyone onto changed git history after filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561998/rebasing-everyone-onto-changed-git-history-after-filter-branch)

The operation I did was on my subproject, on its own repository. This was the operation:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "some_folder/path" -r -f' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

After it I pushed the changes to the subproject own repository:

```
git push origin --force --all
git push origin --force --tags
```

Now I want to integrate the changes on my main repository, where my subproject is a subtree. So, this is not a normal repository. Why I do not see a rebase option on git subtree?

The solution to this would be only this: [git subtree: possible to change subtree branch/path in a forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536279/git-subtree-possible-to-change-subtree-branch-path-in-a-forked-repository), to delete it and readd it?

## Tries

When doing:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=subprojectFolder subprojectRemoteRepository.git
```

The output is:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Using `git subtree merge`:

```
git remote add subproject_remote subprojectRemoteRepository.git
git fetch --no-tags
git checkout master
git subtree merge --prefix=subprojectFolder subproject_remote/master

fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How to make them related?

Doing `--allow-unrelated-histories` just results in:

```
error: unknown option `allow-unrelated-histories'
usage: git subtree add   --prefix=<prefix> <commit>
   or: git subtree add   --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <ref>
   or: git subtree merge --prefix=<prefix> <commit>
   or: git subtree pull  --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <ref>
   or: git subtree push  --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <ref>
   or: git subtree split --prefix=<prefix> <commit...>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am applying this solution right now while there is not something more handy.

#### Part 1

1. To clone the `subproject dedicated repository` and checkout on it.
2. To perform the `filter-branch` operations as I like them.
3. To perform the `git push origin --force --all` and tags.

#### Part 2

1. To clone the `main project` repository and checkout on it.
2. To perform the exactly the same `filter-branch` performed on **Part 1**, and also perform it removing the current subproject tree, or use the  [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner) with:

   ```
   git clone --mirror mainRepository.git
   java -jar bfg.jar --no-blob-protection --delete-folders 'subprojectFolder' mainRepository.git
   cd mainRepository.git
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
   git push origin --force --all
   git push origin --force --tags
   cd ..
   rm -r mainRepository.git
   ```

#### Part 3

1. Finally readd the just cleaned subtree:

   ```
   git clone mainRepository.git
   cd mainRepository
   git checkout master
   git subtree add --prefix=subprojectFolder subproject.git master
   git push
   ```
2. Tell everybody to [Rebasing everyone onto changed git history after filter-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561998/rebasing-everyone-onto-changed-git-history-after-filter-branch) your main project, as well as the subproject dedicated clone, if there exists one.

#### End

1. Note that using [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner) for now, you will only be able to remove the folder if there are no other folders on the main project with the subproject name. This is because the BFG will remove all folders matching the `subprojectFolder` name. The ability to specify a folder path still in development: [How to delete one folder / directory using BFG repo cleaner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254979/how-to-delete-one-folder-directory-using-bfg-repo-cleaner). Otherwise you may use the `filter-branch` to remove the project's `subtree`.
2. For completely erase things do also this from this other answer [Why is my git repository so big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big/1036431#1036431), after finished the `filter-branch`(s) on your repository:

   ```
   rm -Rf .git/refs/original && \
       git reflog expire --expire=now --all && \
       git gc --aggressive && \
       git prune
   ```
3. To list the biggest files use:

   ```
   git rev-list --all --objects | \
       sed -n $(git rev-list --objects --all | \
       cut -f1 -d' ' | \
       git cat-file --batch-check | \
       grep blob | \
       sort -n -k 3 | \
       tail -n40 | \
       while read hash type size; do 
            echo -n "-e s/$hash/$size/p ";
       done) | \
       sort -n -k1
   ```
4. From this other answer, [How to remove unreferenced blobs from my git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo), you might want to do this after the `filter-branch` pull. Remember to readd the origin.

   ```
   git tag | xargs git tag -d && \
   git remote rm origin && \
   rm -rf .git/refs/original/ .git/refs/remotes/ .git/*_HEAD .git/logs/ && \
   git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n1 --no-run-if-empty git update-ref -d && \
   git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 -c gc.rerereresolved=0 \
       -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc "$@"
   ```