# Removing entry with null SHA1, and finding corresponding commit

Tags: git

So, I inherited a repository where one submodule was removed, and I get the dreaded:

```
warning in tree 6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47: nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1
```

I tried to fix this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183847/how-to-remove-an-entry-with-null-sha1-in-a-git-tree). However this assumes that I know which commit included that tree and I cannot find it:

```
git log --pretty='%H %T' | grep 6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47
```

... doesn't return anything. Furthermore, using the `filter-branch` command as the OP of the aforementioned question elicits a complain about a commit, but this is a different tree, and listing this tree with `ls-tree` also show a pair of null SHA1 entries.

So, in summary:

- I seem to have at least two trees with null SHA1 entries
- One is spotted by `fsck` but doesn't seem to be attached to any commit
- Another one is is attached to a commit but is not seen by `fsck`

Maybe I can fix the one belonging to a commit using the aforementioned answer, but how about the orphan tree?

Edit:

Thanks to all suggestions here. Having a copy of the repo on a tmpfs on a fast machine makes testing all this a breeze. Eventually figured out part of the problem:

- The commit `filter-branch` complains about (e884a3b0) contains tree e057f815a
- Tree e057f815a contains just a tree : 6eb01385f
- Tree 6eb01385f is the tree with two null SHA-1s tha `fsck` complains about

Now I wonder how to apply the official answer since the troublesome tree isn't a direct child of the commit. As I understand it I should fix/replace 
6eb01385f and reinsert that in e057f815a, and maybe then regen e057f815a to insert it in commit e884a3b0. So that would be:

- `git ls-tree {badtree} | sed -e '/0\{40\}/d' | git mktree` to fix the bottom tree
- `git ls-tree {parenttree} | sed -e 's/badtree/fixedtree/' | git mktree` to make a parent tree pointing to it
- replace that one in the commit as indicated in that other answer

OK, so tried the hard way:

```
# Create new tree by removing empty SHA1s
git ls-tree 6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47 | sed -e '/0\{40\}/d' | git mktree
0eabc1625026f92b2737e763a087f7c4000f0084

# Create new parent tree by replacing bad tree by fixed tree in parent tree
git ls-tree e057f815aec33a48981921289fc7ab25e9ea1a16 | sed -e 's/6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47/0eabc1625026f92b2737e763a087f7c4000f0084/' | git mktree
df56fe08e90f1a30e6467ac2bba50a3d771c9de4

# Create new commit by replacing old parent tree by new parent tree
git cat-file commit e884a3b0040b3940d259cd72d82be20d5eb8d7c3 | sed 's/e057f815aec33a48981921289fc7ab25e9ea1a16/df56fe08e90f1a30e6467ac2bba50a3d771c9de4/' | git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin
b41674793c985ba63bc68b095024ebcb2fbf0370

# Replace old commit by new commit
git replace e884a3b0040b3940d259cd72d82be20d5eb8d7c3 b41674793c985ba63bc68b095024ebcb2fbf0370
```

So far so good. But the old commit and trees are still there. And if I rey to remove them with:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Somedir1 Somedir2' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

It complains that I should use "-r", so I use:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch Somedir1 Somedir2' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

which runs... but then the submodules have been replaced by directories that have the same name at the same place, so the above also drops a lot of useful files. And `fsck` still finds the bad tree, and in addition it finds many "dangling tags". Is there a way to just remove the two bad trees and the commit?

Comment: Add `--all` to your `git log` command to view all reachable commits; but this may also not find it, if the null hash is in a tree that is not a top level tree. Use a recursive tree searcher if necessary to find such sub-trees.

Comment: Didn't suffice and indeed the tree isn't a top-level tree. But thanks, still a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force will probably do the trick:

```
which-commits-use-tree () 
{ 
    local REPLY;
    git rev-list --all --reflog | while read; do
            git ls-tree -dr $REPLY | grep -q $1 && echo $REPLY uses $1;
    done
}
```

That's sort of tolerable as a one-off on medium-ish repos, it scanned the whole of git's history in about five minutes on my little system.  If you've got anything substantially larger, you'll need patience or something heavier duty.

```
git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype)' --batch-all-objects --buffer \
| awk '/commit|tree/{print $1}' | git cat-file --batch | your-scanner-here
```

is about the fastest way I can think of to dump the entire history structure for bulk scanning, that took six seconds on the git history;  on the linux repo it took about 2m30, that's reasonably encouraging.  I'm probably not going to write the scanner for this, though.

Comment: OK, so I guess that with this answer I figured out the problem, and edited my original question. Still need a bit if help for the "fix" part.

Comment: What happens if you do `git replace --edit 6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47` deleting the bad entry followed by `git filter-branch --index-filter : --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`?

Comment: I get `error: object 0eabc1625026f92b2737e763a087f7c4000f0084 is a tree, not a commit
error: object 0eabc1625026f92b2737e763a087f7c4000f0084 is a tree, not a commit
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/replace/6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47^0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
WARNING: Ref 'refs/replace/6eb01385fa82fdef80719ec4990bec2e0b591d47' is unchanged`. `ls-tree` doesn't show the null SHA'1s, but `fsck` still finds them.

Comment: Did it rewrite the rest of the history?  filter-branch keeps refs to the original history under refs/original, so fsck is still going to find the original bad objects until you delete those and repack.

Comment: Yes, rest seems to have been rewritten. How do I delete/repack?

Comment: Okay, the error was just filter-branch trying to treat the replace ref as a branch, you can ignore that one.  You can push the rewritten refs where you like, they should be fixed.  You can also `git for-each-ref refs/original refs/replace --format='delete %(refname)'|git update-ref --stdin; git repack -ad` to do it locally.

Comment: Still problems with 'fsck'

Comment: Actually, the tree I edited has been replaced by its original version...  (this is caused by the `for-each-ref`...

Comment: Tried some more things. I may need a way to selective remove one given commit.