# On git clone receiving "Cache entry has null sha1 value"

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I attempt to do a git clone on my git repository I get the following error:

```
$ git clone https://xxxxxxxxx:8081/scm/xxxxxx/xxxx-apac.git
Cloning into 'xxxx-apac'...
remote: Counting objects: 740, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (471/471), done.
remote: Total 740 (delta 304), reused 466 (delta 201)
Receiving objects: 100% (740/740), 5.28 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (304/304), done.
error: cache entry has null sha1: bin
fatal: unable to write new index file
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'


/c/Users/bala/Bala/project
$ cd xxxx-apac/

/c/Users/bala/Bala/project/xxxx-apac (xxxx_Apr2018)
$ git branch --all
* xxxx_Apr2018
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/xxxx_Apr2018
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/xxxx_Apr2018
  remotes/origin/xxxxx_mReleases2018
```

My clone fails and the local directory is not empty. Anyway to fix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an entry with null sha1 in a Git tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183847/how-to-remove-an-entry-with-null-sha1-in-a-git-tree)

Comment: I am just doing a clone.

Comment: Can you checkout master to see if that works?

Answer (score 2):

This is typical of a symbolic link or a submodule entry incorrectly added (as [in this example](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/On-git-clone-receiving-quot-Cache-entry-has-null-sha1-value-quot/qaq-p/269031)): you can check how 'bin' is represented in the remote hosting service (GitHUb? GitLab? BitBucket) to confirm this.

If you can apply the solution from "[How to remove an entry with null sha1 in a Git tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228418/6309)" (even in your empty working tree) *and* if you have the right to force push (`git push --force`) the result, you might be able to fix that repo for others.