# .idea from pycharm unable to be removed

Tags: git, github, pycharm

Hi so I created new repository from pycharm but didn't add gitignore at first so it also uploaded .idea folder.
I tried to delete it from github by creating new text file and placing git command there:

```
git rm --cached .idea
```

However the .idea folder is still in the repository. 
How can I delete it?

Comment: Try `-r`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: silly question: did you push the changes?

Comment: I mean I created the text file in the master branch in github and then merged evertyhing (including the gitignore) from pycharm. Should I do it some other way?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at my repo: https://github.com/datainvestor/scraperino

Comment: Please see this answer, It will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32886427/4214976

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a terminal (or git bash, or even put this on your file, but I recommend the terminal solution) and execute this line:

```
git rm -r --cached .idea
```

Which will remove your folder from the repository but **not** from your local machine.

Good luck :)