# Remove moved files from history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a repository in which there is a "Trash" folder with a lot of trash files (previous developer wanted to store them for whatever reason). I want to completely remove them from repo, as they take almost 1.5 GB of space. I already saw such problem: [Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history#) but mine is a little bit different: initially "Trash" files were somewhere else, so I need to:

1. Get all files from "Trash"
2. Find all references of them in history
3. Remove every notion of them from history

How can it be done?

Comment: Not entirely clear: Do you just want to delete the Trash folder and all the files therein from history, or do you also want to remove the files that were moved to trash _before_ they were moved to trash? In the latter case, checking out an older version might leave you with an incomplete codebase.

Comment: (Yes, latter case) Agree, I'll lose stablility of previous commits, so I have 3 options: a) forget about history, create a fresh new repo and make one big "Initial commit", b) use BFG to remove just big files from history, c) somehow completely purge files from "Trash". I chose latter one.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for
>   cleansing bad data out of your Git repository history
>
> Faster : [10 - 720x faster](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#speed)
>
> Simpler : The BFG isn't particularily clever, but is focused on making
>   the above tasks easy

examples:

Delete folder named 'myfolder':

```
bfg --delete-folders myfolder  my-repo.git
```

Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :

```
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

Remove all blobs bigger than 50 megabytes :

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M  my-repo.git
```

Remove all folders or files named '.git' - a reserved filename in Git. These often become a problem when migrating to Git from other source-control systems like Mercurial :

```
bfg --delete-folders .git --delete-files .git  --no-blob-protection  my-repo.git
```