# Remove Folder from bitbucket history

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

I am new to git repository. I have a 2gb limit in bitbucket and bymistake I added one `images` folder of 1.5 gb and pushed the code.

Now the bitbucket size is 1.8gb. To remove the folder from history I followed these steps.

[Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf import/images' --prune-empty HEAD
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git 
update-ref -d
echo import/images/ >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Removing images from git history'
git gc
git push origin master --force
```

I followed these steps and checked in my previous commits and the folder is removed.  but `git count-objects -v` still gives the size-pack of 1.8gb

Also in the bitbucket repository settings its still showing 1.8gb

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are a beginner in git and don't want to delete your project or some file accidentally , I would suggest an alternate way. You can create a new repository and leave the current repository as-is, and push your current code without images into the new repository. This will let you access the history of your commits done before this (in case you need it, at some point in time), through the older repository and you can work on the new repository thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to bitbucket page in order to delete a file/files.

1. Go inside your repo,
2. select source (left panel)
3. pick your branch
4. find your folder
5. go inside and delete all the images you have there (there is the delete option top right where there are 3 clickable dots)

You can't delete the folder like that (for some reason bitbucket allows only file delete and branch delete manually) but you can always empty the folder manually and remove it through console in the next git push.

**Caution.** This work like a "hard delete" so be extra careful when you use it, and don't use it if you can use git commands.

*Edit*

```
 git gc --prune=now  //accepts date
```

Have a look at this [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) there are quite a few options that may suit your problem.

Another approach is the git filter-branch --force. More about this command you can find [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). This command is specifically for "rewriting"  git history so it will do your job. It's tricky but it will do.

One last and final approach (never used this one to be honest) is 3rd party software (Really secure as even atlassian includes it in their documentation) but is in java so first you will need to install java in order to run a java command in your console.  I saw your php tag so i just leave this as last just to concider it. I leave ths link [here](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Comment: thanks @pr1nc3 but the folder is already deleted with the above commands. Only the size is not reduced.

Comment: Edited my answer