# git -"<<<<<<< HEAD .." in source

Tags: git, git-merge

Why does git occasionally write markup to my source code such as the following?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  <component name="JavaScriptSettings">
    <option name="languageLevel" value="ES6" />
  </component>
=======
>>>>>>> 02d2be40f4d48e8bcddbd819c19e3c01c4e690c4
```

where everything between `HEAD` and `=======` is source code and the rest is markup git seems to have been using for tracking and merging changes. In my case, these appeared after attempting to remove a folder from the history using filter-branch:

[Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)

Is this possibly something IntelliJ is injecting?

Comment: it means you have an unresolved conflict during a `git pull` or (more likely) a `git merge` command. See here for help on how to resolve the conflicts: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html

Comment: this is definitely a duplicate, but I was striking out searching the `<<<<<<< HEAD` string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These markers mean that there was a conflict in your code (maybe after pulling), and you probably just marked the file as resolved instead of actually resolving the conflict.

IntelliJ IDEA has nothing to do with this, though it provides a nice instrument of resolving conflicts in the `Version Control` panel.