# Accidentally pushed git history of package author

Tags: git

I started developing a chatbot using botkit, but when creating a new bot project, the cli tool cloned the current botkit repo.

When I pushed my code to the company's git server and the client's azure machine (and later merged azure into ours) I suddenly saw the entire history of botkit. I suspect that the old .git folder was accidentally pushed to azure.

How can I remove this history while keeping the rest of the history intact?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove folder and its contents from git/GitHub's history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067848/remove-folder-and-its-contents-from-git-githubs-history)